# Ubuntu 14.04 - 14.10 - 15,04 wifi disconnection

Tags: wireless

my laptop with this wifi card:

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2231
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Have many wifi problems.

After some minutes, i can't navigate or use the mail or ping something, i simply disable and enable the wifi and all work again.

Actually i have ubuntu 15.04 for some reason, but the same happen also with 14.04 or 14.10.

Comment: What kernel is 15.04 using as the normal fix might not work? `uname -a` and `modinfo -p rtl8723be`

Comment: uname -a


Linux HPU 3.19.0-9-generic #9-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 11 17:50:03 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux



 modinfo -p rtl8723be




swlps: (bool)
swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
 (bool)
ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)

debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)


Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`
and reboot to see if it helps.

If can change the router settings, see if the encryption is set to WPA2 only with no TKIP enabled, change it from auto channel to a fixed channel and see if it helps.

In 14.04, I recommend that the 3.19 backports be used as it fixes most issues with the RTL8723BE

Comment: Hi, well after 5 days, it seems with your first command , the connection is stable.  Let me check some more days.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

You will need to have the package with the kernel headers installed.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Hello, after over 2 hours everything seems ok now, but i let you know what happen.  Thank you

Comment: Hello,today same issue, wif connected but i can't make traffic.

Thank you