# How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop with RTL8723BE Wi-fi card. But it is always disconnecting from network. I have tried `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` but that didn't helped. What can I do to prevent the wifi from disconnecting? If I upgrade to kernel 4.X, will it help?

`~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be


~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


~$ ifconfig && iwconfig && route -n && ping -c 1 google.com
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:63:bb:cd:4a:7e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:752 (752.0 B)  TX bytes:8445 (8.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3870 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3870 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:314613 (314.6 KB)  TX bytes:314613 (314.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:38:96:6d:c4:83  
          inet addr:192.168.1.205  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c238:96ff:fe6d:c483/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14627 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14410285 (14.4 MB)  TX bytes:2192744 (2.1 MB)

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"DIR-615"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:90:4C:08:00:0D   
          Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-22 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:186   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    400    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
PING google.com.Dlink (172.26.136.19) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 19.136.26.172.in-addr.arpa (172.26.136.19): icmp_seq=1 ttl=249 time=102 ms

--- google.com.Dlink ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 102.547/102.547/102.547/0.000 ms
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add output of `rfkill list` command.

Comment: Please add output of `ifconfig && iwconfig && route -n && ping -c 1 google.com`

Comment: Your wireless network works well. You can ping google OK. Does google open in your browser?

Comment: Now I can ping google.com, work but after 10-15 min the connection drops. Thanks a lot for help. How can I remove this drivers if I want to test this ones: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

Comment: These are the same drivers :-)) I just packed them as dkms to my ppa. You can remove everything by `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi`.

Comment: :)) I didn't knew :D Thanks for help.

Comment: And also remove the setting `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

Comment: I will test the drivers for some time, I still want to use Ubuntu, not Windows:( Hop in kernel 4.x to fix this problem

Comment: It is not fixed in 4.0 yet. But this driver works well for most of the people. There is nothing better yet.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

First of all remove the settings you made.

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

If you do not have this file, nothing is wrong.

Then install a good driver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

Reboot and enjoy

If you still have problems (low signal), you may need to add an option:

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

then reboot again.

Expanation is made by **chili555** in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/729660/167850).

This is the same driver as https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new, `rock.new_btcoex` branch but packed as dkms.

You can see all that at https://github.com/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi_new/tree/rock.new_btcoex

If you also need bluetooth working, run also:

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8723au-bt-dkms linux-firmware
```

**Note:** Support for 4.2 kernels and Ubuntu 15.10 has been added to the PPA. For kernel 4.2 the bluetooth driver should **not** be installed from the PPA. There is already native support of the bluetooth adapter in kernel 4.2.

**Offline guide**

If you do not have any internet connection, you can download the package using another computer, a phone, etc.

The package is [HERE](https://launchpad.net/%7Ehanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.10_all.deb)

You will also need `DKMS` installed. You can find the DKMS package for Ubuntu 16.04 [HERE](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb)

Copy these two files to the Ubuntu Home folder (~/) and run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb rtlwifi*.deb
```

Then reboot.

**Important:** For new Ubuntu  kernels installed on a system with Secure Boot on UEFI, the unsigned kernel module may not load. In this case see [THIS ANSWER](https://askubuntu.com/a/762255/167850) to fix it.

**Update:** I have now a laptop with this adapter. It works perfectly on the 4.8 kernel that is available in Ubuntu 16.10 and 16.04.2.

## Installation of a custom driver is required only for kernels older than 4.8.

I suggest installing the 4.8 kernel to Ubuntu 16.04 if it is not installed yet by

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

The device should work well after a reboot.

But still if your laptop has only one antenna and it is attached to a "wrong" connector, setting `ant_sel=2`, or `and_sel=1` may be required.

Comment: No, I don't need bluetooth to work, I don't use it, I will trie this driver and I will return with an answer. Thanks

Comment: I have tested this drivers, they doesn't work, I keeps disconnecting from network.

Comment: Did they install without errors?

Comment: Yes, installation was fine.

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: yes, I rebooted

Comment: Try this `echo "options rtl8723be msi=1 ips=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` and reboot again.

Comment: No, not working at all :(

Comment: This is weird. This chip works well with this driver. Does it connect and then disconnect, or does not connect at all?

Comment: It connects but no internet acces. I can't browse the net :(

Comment: Oh, that must be some other problem. Please reword your question.

Comment: The drivers work but after 20-15 min there is no internet connection, after 5 minutes the wifi works. Thanks.

Comment: If you found the reason maybe remove /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf

Comment: It work with this configuration file, I don't want to touch anything :) better this way than nothing :)

Comment: @Pilot6 For me doing all the steps you mentioned above worked! I had to not use the "/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf" file though. I deleted it and everything was perfect.

Comment: @Pilot6 I think, it is working fine now. What does `ant_sel 2` actually do?

Comment: It selects the correct antenna. There is a link in the answer where you can read what it does.

Comment: Thanks! This answer always helps me, works on Lubuntu 16.04

Comment: Only worked after `options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N swenc=Y msi=1`. With `options rtl8723be msi=1 ips=0` only didn't work.

Comment: Usually works for me after `options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N swenc=Y msi=1 ant_sel=2`

Comment: Interestingly, installing `rtlwifi-new-dkms` from this PPA on 16.04 (where the kernel is 4.4.0 out of the box) gave me substantial improvements in wifi reliability too. This seems at odds with what you're saying about mainline support from 4.2.  Or are you only talking about bluetooth there?

Comment: I wrote about bluetooth support. Wi-Fi is not well supported yet. That is why I keep building this driver for Xenial.

Comment: @Pilot6 ah yes, I spoke too soon. Wifi is still dropping out, but it does seem to recover quicker. I will try some of the configuration options.

Comment: Even with `ant_sel=2` it's still pretty flakey. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @detly I had the same problem. After updating the driver there were still frequently disconnects. I found a trick how it works perfectly for me without any disconnects. See my answer http://askubuntu.com/a/847528/247771

Comment: I can confirm that this works perfectly on laptops from the *HP 15* series with the Realtek RTL8723be on Ubuntu 16.04. It requires both the installation of `rtlwifi-new-dkms` from `ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi` and writing the `ant_sel=2` directive. Unfortunately, it requires you to disable Secure Boot. But on all Ubuntu versions that ship with a more recent kernel, e.g. Ubuntu 16.04.2, you can probably remove this custom driver again, right? Then, after switching back from this driver to the one provided by the kernel, it should be possible to enable Secure Boot again.

Comment: This worked for me, except that wifi kept toggling off when I put it to on.  This was solved using another of Pilot6's suggestions, blacklisting acer:  sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"

Comment: Just want to mention that it's worth trying attena 1 which for me works. Many thanks @Pilot6

Comment: So a while ago I already stumbled upon this and it worked just fine installing the new module manually by building it from the sources (rtlwifi_new git repo). Out of the sudden it went back to being very bad. Reinstalled module and added the options with ant_sel=2 and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: did not work for me.

Comment: Is there any way to check if the system uses indeed the new driver? The command `lshw -C network` gives `rtl8723be, driver version=4.4.0-179-generic`.

Answer (score 7):

#### If your Wifi drops after a while and you dual boot with Windows

On HP 250 G4 (using rtl8723be), I at first had the **antenna bug**: wifi signal was too low:

It was solved after installing new driver and setting `ant_sel=2`,  just as described here.

But then came the 2nd problem :
wifi was working fine for some time (sometimes 2 hours) then suddenly going slow and eventually disconnecting.
Changing parameters (ips, fwps...) didn't help.
I finally found that **removing Windows 10 fastboot** (in Windows energy settings) solved the problem.

This has been confirmed by another user (see [RTL8723BE: Wifi always drops after 15/20 mins](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/126)

Comment: What does antenna selection do? What antenna are we talking here exactly? Does the hardware has 2 antennas?

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was enabling the MSI parameter (message signal interupt). I have a lenovo Z50 laptop. My wifi would work with all wifi laptop manufacturers but i was having a problem with a Lancorm wifi router at a Hotel I once stayed.

I found the file `sw.c` in the folder path

```
/home/peter/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be
```

Then in the `sw.c` file, I added the variable `.msi_support` and initiated it to "false" under the data type

```
rtl_mod_params rtl8723be_mod_params
```

i.e

```
static struct rtl_mod_params rtl8723be_mod_params = {
.sw_crypto = false,
.inactiveps = true,
.swctrl_lps = false,
.fwctrl_lps = true,
.msi_support = false,
};
```

Since `msi_support` is by default disabled, we have to appropriately initialize it as disabled(hence false),

I then complied the code:

```
cd rtl8723be
make clean
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

After that I set the msi parameter to 1, in the file

```
/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

it should contain

```
options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N swenc=Y msi=1
```

You may have to reboot the computer and wait after for a couple of minutes after restarting the browser for the msi to be triggered.

This worked for a lenovo z50. Depending on your pc, you may toggle and choose instead an msi of 0

Answer (score 3):

Just took a HP Stream 13 and wiped it, put Ubuntu 15.10 on it symlinking all home folders to a 64GB SD card to expand the 32GB SSD... Then ran into the dreaded rtl8723be problem, which I have also noticed on a HP 430 work laptop that had a different variant....

After a lot of messing, I finally find there is actually 2 issues here.

1. The WiFi driver needs swapping as stated above, to cure drop outs of the card which require network manager to be restarted or card resynched with network. Update the driver as stated.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
   ```
2. Once your drop outs are fixed, you need to cure the low signal strength issue... This is a little more invasive. Undo all screws on bottom, even the ones under the 2 back rubber feet, centre little rubber cover and hinge rubber covers all on the bottom.

Gently ease the top off clicking it away from the base. Lift top off gently. Locate the network card in the centre, towards the rear. Remove the fine coax cable of the antenna connected (main) and replace it on the connector next to it (aux). Put everything back together.

The driver for Linux uses the other antenna on this dual antenna card, so if you don't swap it you will get severe signal loss.

Now the laptop has plenty of space for storage, boots pretty quick and has full signal with no dropouts all around the house. Great little laptop for the price but needs some planning if you are gonna put Linux on it.

Thanks everyone for the work on this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I updated my driver just as explaind in [Pilot6 answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/635629/247771) , but it still frequently disconnected. I was desperatly searching for another solution when I found in [laugeo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/793912/247771) that **removing Windows 10 fastboot** solves the problem. Unfortunalty, I only have Ubuntu and no Windows. However I found that simply disabling **Legacy Support** solves the problem!

I had to go to disable Legacy Support in Bios like this:

**Bios -> Boot Option (Enter) -> Legacy Support: Disabled**

[image]

Now WLAN works perfectly - no more disconnects!

Comment: Disabling Secure Boot you allowed the system to use the installed driver.

Answer (score 0):

This was the same case with me. I also tried *rfkill list all* but nothing was blocked. Yet Wi-fi failed to work properly.

[My *rfkill list all* result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxOEe.png)

For 2 days long since installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I tried various tweaks. Was almost frustrated and loosing hope. Finally got it working.

**Possible solution** - After trying different tweaks I came across one code which seems to work. Go to terminal, copy-paste the following command and run it -

*echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf*

Then you need to reboot once. Now I'm able to access the internet through Wi-Fi without any drop.

Good luck!

Comment: @pilot6 how does this answer seems? Is it fine? Does it meets community standards? Please reply. Looking forward to learn from you. I'm just 2 days old in here you see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you using the latest version of Ubuntu such as 18.04 and above, you won't be able to add the ppa repository[ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi] due to some security reasons.

Therefore, get that new wifi driver directly from GitHub.

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new
```

Build it.

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make
```

Finally, install it.

```
sudo make install
```

That's it the updated driver is installed.