# Wifi not working (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, realtek-wireless

My Ubuntu 14.04 install doesn't connect to any WiFi network I have access to.

All the required information should hopefully be [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/818343013245f149aa8e).

Let me know if you need to know anything else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the driver this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

and reboot.

If you want bluetooth working, run also

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8723au-bt-dkms
```