# Transitioning from Ubuntu to Xubuntu

Tags: wireless, system-installation, xubuntu, realtek

I wish to transition from the current LTS release of Ubuntu to Xubuntu. However, I had a major issue when I first installed Ubuntu, where the wifi would disconnect after about five or ten minutes of usage. That was fixed with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem) helpful solution, where the problem was simply bad drivers.

However, would I have to do something similar with Xubuntu? Or is it possible to check that by booting from a live USB of Xubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wireless solution will work for Xubuntu as well.

All Ubuntu flavors share same kernels and drivers. And all hardware related solutions work with all flavors similarly.

All terminal commands that are not specific to Xubuntu desktop environment are also same.

Comment: Does it use the same terminal commands as well?

Comment: Yes, it uses same commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can even “transform” Ubuntu into Xubuntu by simply installing

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Once it's installed, you should be able to select xfce at login and get, basically, the Xubuntu experience. It's not *quite* the same as an out-of-the-box Xubuntu, but differences are mostly in artwork. If it doesn't work, just switch back to Unity at the next login.

As Carl H remarks, you can actually get the artwork etc. too by installing `xubuntu-desktop` rather than just `xfce4`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but I did not miss anything Ubuntu-specific so I thought of simply installing Xubuntu and have the full experience of it. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: For a full Xubuntu system (rather than just the XFCE desktop), it's `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`