# Ubuntu internet stops working after a few minutes. Wifi stays connected though

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, internet, realtek-wireless

Recently, the Internet was been acting strange on my Ubuntu partition.  It works 100% fine when I dual-boot Windows, but the Ubuntu partition connects to wifi for an indeterminate amount of time (0-10 minutes) before dying and not-working...

I'm running 14.04, which I installed and re-installed yesterday.

`ping 8.8.8.8` usually works for a few minutes after I power on my laptop, but after that it returns the Host Unreachable error.

I have read several articles on this site on the same issue and cannot find a solution.  I've attached terminal output from several commands I saw users asking for:

`route -n` output: **I don't know much about what's going on, but this looks erroneous**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.98.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.31.98.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

`grep wl /etc/modprobe.d/*` output:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-watchdog.conf:blacklist twl4030_wdt
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:remove iwlwifi \
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
```

`rfkill list` output:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`iwconfig` output:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Google Starbucks"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 18:64:72:65:86:20   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-33 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:42   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`ifconfig` output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:ee:75:28:64:8d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:16928 (16.9 KB)  TX bytes:16928 (16.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b0:10:41:8a:ee:47  
          inet addr:172.31.99.170  Bcast:172.31.99.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b210:41ff:fe8a:ee47/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:198 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:341 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:257409 (257.4 KB)  TX bytes:34163 (34.1 KB)
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03eb:8a1b Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:055d Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3810]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Comment: not the same, the linked problem makes no mention of the wifi working.  I have reinstalled drivers on Windows and Ubuntu and the problem persists only on Ubuntu.  Not the same as the linked problem

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu drivers? Windows drivers are not related at all. And this is exactly same problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 you are right, this is the same issue.  Nonetheless the problem went away when I reinstalled the wlan drivers on my Windows partition (related or not, it went away)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by re-installing the drivers offered by Lenovo on my Windows partition.  Even though the problem was with Ubuntu, and even though the drivers were previously installed (hence me being able to initially connect to the Internet on Ubuntu), the re-installing of the Lenovo drivers on my Windows partition somehow fixed the Ubuntu dropped connection issue as well

Comment: Turn off the computer, then on and boot right into Ubuntu. You will see the problem again. But you need to turn of Windows fully.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for the downvote.  I let my machine `ping 8.8.8.8` overnight and `ping` is still running.  Before reinstalling the drivers, `ping` would fail after five minutes (roughly).  I guess there's no way to "prove" the problem is gone, since that would require infinite time, but I feel comfortable saying it's gone (since ping has been working for about 100x longer than before).

Comment: It is gone, because Windows uploaded the firmware to the adapter. If you boot to Ubuntu from fully off computer, you will get same problem. And not everyone has Windows installed. So if you are happy with that, it's OK.

Comment: I did boot Ubuntu from fully off.  Windows is not running or asleep or anything, because I did the full shutdown (shift+shutdown) not the quick shutdown.  I have verified that the problem has went away, it is no longer here.  I have the machine in front of me and am typing into it now via the Internet