# Can't connect to certain wifi network or if connects then internet is unavailable within sometime

Tags: wireless, network-manager, internet, 17.04

After cleanly dual booting my new Dell Vostro 3568 with Windows 10 & Ubuntu 17.04, I am facing this issue. It happens in both the partitions.
I have referred following threads & others as well, but no luck:

- [Can't connect to a specific WiFi network (Ubuntu 14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/q/567799/22704)
- [Ubuntu internet stops working after a few minutes. Wifi stays connected though](https://askubuntu.com/q/653994/22704)

Have tried to reinstall all the Dell drivers from Windows partition, but the issue persists. Basically my PC easily connects to most of the wifi networks, but it faces problems with certain network, which is a leased line and connected to a Ruckus router [with/without firewall].

Here is the [pastebin output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24467040), which is derived from [this forum link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108). I am able to connect with "AAHLAAD_AirtelBB" (as seen in pastebin), but unable to connect with "AAHLAAD_Production". Reinstalling (without uninstalling) the network manager didn't help.

Kindly help!

**Update** (12-Jun-2017): Though I fixed the wifi connection issue (see [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/911002/301745)), the internet connection issue is still not fixed. I even tried the solution described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290024/20226) as well, but no luck. The problem still persists, where the internet works fine for less than a minute and then it doesn't work at all. The wifi remains connected though.

**Bounty** (28-Aug-2017): Had posted this problem in Ubuntu forums as well, but no luck so far. Hence starting a bounty.
[Ubuntu Wifi connected but no internet (internet remains for short time)](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365921)

Comment: When you say "both the partitions", do you mean both OS's?

Comment: @wjandrea, yes. I have dual OS Win10 & Ubuntu 17.04. This issue happens only in Ubuntu side, where 1 particular Wi-Fi out of total 3 would connect but internet stops after 1 minute. The same Wi-Fi works in all other MacOS, Ubuntu, Windows & mobiles.

Comment: OK, you should edit your question and answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply installing the Broadcom driver worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

---

I reinstalled all the drivers in Windows partition as suggested in one of the linked posts. That actually fixed the Windows side of issue. The drivers were available in the Dell's official website where I had to provide my machine number to download the required drivers.

Comment: Huh? You don't even have a Broadcom device according to the wireless diagnostic log.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, out of desperation, I did try some things and it appeared at that time that those worked. But later I realised that they don't as I expected. It seems that there is something wrong in 17.04 compared to 16.10 which causes this wireless disconnection issue. See this thread: [Serious Wi-Fi network issue on Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/905997/22704). The solutions presented there are not helping me. Fortunately other wifi-s are working well with me, except this main one.