# How to get Wifi driver lo lenovo g50-70 assembled with RTL8723BE

Tags: wireless, drivers, lenovo

I have newly installed ubuntu-14.04 in my laptop but the WiFi is not working on browsing the net.

I have tried some methods that are presented but none of the made favour to me, I have gone through the `/etc/modprobe.d/` to check the `rtl8723be.conf` but it was not present.

Comment: Do not worry about `rtl8723be.conf`. It is not needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to intall new driver.

```
 sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git  
 git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git  
 cd rtlwifi_new   
 make  
 sudo make install  
 sudo reboot
```