# Short realtek rtl8723be wifi range when using ubuntu 14.04 laptop

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, realtek

The range of wifi is very limited, less than 10 ft whereas the smart phones connected to the same router can operate at a distance of up 40 ft (apprx).

This is a new  HP laptop, bought with DOS pre-installed and then installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it. The wifi hardware is 'rtl8723be'.  Based on other answers on this site I have re-installed the driver but that has not made any difference to the distance at which I can operate. I can work continuously for hours within the distance range of 10 feet. (no 30 minute connection dropping as has been reported by some other users)

Please help me resolve the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I bought a new laptop a few weeks ago and had the same problem, then I found https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/28 and change the antenna position as Ghost says.

Here is the picture he adds to guide you (the antenna was connected to the pin on the right side) now my wifi works correctly.

[image: http://i65.tinypic.com/vql568.jpg]

I know its late, but just in case anyone else has the same problem can try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to set the parameters in the driver that determine which antenna to use.

The parameter is `ant_sel` and I was able to solve the problem by setting the value of this parameter to `2`.

Use the following command to get the list of parameters and permissible values:

```
sudo modinfo rtl8723be
```

The command to set the parameter:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be

echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf"

sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

Please reboot the system and then check your wifi connectivity.

I am getting good connectivity even at 30 feet,