# Wireless connection drops

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

I have a brand new Hp 15 r215nt notebook. I have just installed 14.04 LTS. I noticed that wireless connection drops after sometime and needs a startup. (Disconnect/Connect wifi doesn't help) If I connect powercord I don't have this problem. Is there any solution?

```
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Power cord or LAN cable?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Power cord!.

Comment: @Pilot 6   0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
        Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Run this command and reboot:

`echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

Answer (score 0):

If Power Management is on, your wifi card will stop working after some time to save power especially when power cord not plugged in. So check whether Power Management is on using `iwconfig`

for restarting wifi use `sudo service network-manager restart`