# Wireless network disabled

Tags: networking, wireless

i have a hp pavillion laptop. i have installed ubuntu 15.04. for the first time ubuntu has problem detecting wireless network.
i am posting data here. if anyone could help me out it would be of great help to me

```
    ======== Wireless-Info START ========

System-Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

maripuri 3.19.0-26-generic x86_64,  Ubuntu 15.04, vivid

CPU    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
Memory : 3880 MB
Uptime : 07:08:39 up 23:37,  2 users,  load average: 0.14, 0.29, 0.23


lspci ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8096]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169


lsusb ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b50c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


PCMCIA Card Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



iwconfig ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off



rfkill ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      Interface        Soft blocked  Hard blocked
0: phy0: Wireless LAN      no            yes


lsmod ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

rtl8723be              94208  0 
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              724992  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
hp_wmi                 16384  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
cfg80211              540672  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    20480  3 hp_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau


module parameters ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

cfg80211      (2): cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz=N | ieee80211_regdom=00
mac80211      (6): beacon_loss_count=7 | ieee80211_default_rc_algo=minstrel_ht | max_nullfunc_tries=2 | max_probe_tries=5 | minstrel_vht_only=Y | probe_wait_ms=500
rtl8723be     (6): debug=0 | disable_watchdog=N | fwlps=Y | ips=Y | swenc=N | swlps=N
wmi           (2): debug_dump_wdg=N | debug_event=N


nm-tool ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


================o======o========o========o=========o===========o==============o===========
 Interface & ID | Type | Driver | State  | Default | Speed     | Support      | HW Addr   
================o======o========o========o=========o===========o==============o===========
                |      |        |        |         |           |              |           
----------------+------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------


NetworkManager.state ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true


NetworkManager.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC ID removed>,

[ifupdown]
managed=false


NM WiFi Profiles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Hotspot              : ssid=maripuri | autoconnect=false | mac-address=<MAC wlan0> | ipv4=shared | ipv6=auto 
Maripuri             : ssid=Maripuri | mac-address=<MAC wlan0> | ipv4=auto | ipv6=auto 
netgear1334          : ssid=netgear1334 | mac-address=<MAC wlan0> | ipv4=auto | ipv6=auto 


interfaces ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

resolv.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

nameserver 127.0.1.1


Routes & Ping ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth7
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth7
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth7

--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.374/0.390/0.407/0.025 ms

--- 127.0.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.019/0.021/0.024/0.005 ms


iw reg get ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

(Region : "en_IN")
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR


iwlist chan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 (2.412 GHz) - 13 (2.472 GHz)


iwlist scan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



blacklist ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci


modinfo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
srcversion:     5C50A9DE21B06ED4EC09E5F
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
parm:           swlps:bool
parm:           swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
parm:           ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
parm:           fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)

[btcoexist]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/btcoexist/btcoexist.ko
srcversion:     0C170EE6883C780D98D7EC3
depends:        

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
srcversion:     251C540A2D3AD38CCA85ED9
depends:        

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
srcversion:     A25DC6D8C53D55DA133BC49
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
srcversion:     35016235A31CEB1854418E1
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-26-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
srcversion:     DF4E06FB15FF0707074A816
depends:        cfg80211
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[hp_wmi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/hp-wmi.ko
srcversion:     10FA3A7A83BC5E7F2D45E22
depends:        wmi,sparse-keymap

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-26-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
srcversion:     F28307769349A31F4B24FC2
depends:        
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[mxm_wmi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/mxm-wmi.ko
srcversion:     D566C16ECB7E11FB9DF5C84
depends:        wmi

[wmi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/wmi.ko
srcversion:     2E987FE96F7EBB6BFC7E2B2
depends:        
parm:           debug_event:Log WMI Events [0/1] (bool)
parm:           debug_dump_wdg:Dump available WMI interfaces [0/1] (bool)


udev rules ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC eth0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC eth1>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC eth2>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC eth3>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth3"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC eth4>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth4"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC eth5>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth5"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC eth6>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth6"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC eth7>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth7"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0xb723 (rtl8723be)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC wlan0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"


Custom files/entries ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/etc/modules        : Default
/etc/rc.local       : Default
/etc/modprobe.d     : Not Default
/etc/pm/(cnf|pw|sl) : Not Default

[/etc/modprobe.d]
iwlwifi.conf      : remove iwlwifi \
                    (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
                    && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
mlx4.conf         : softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en
modesetting.conf  : options cirrus modeset=1
                    options mgag200 modeset=1
qemu-system-x86.conf: options kvm_intel nested=1
rtl8188ee.confReboot.: options rtl8188ee ips=0 fwlps=0

[/etc/pm/power.d/95hdparm-apm] [executable]
#!/bin/sh
# tlp - if tlp is enabled, override corresponding script
#       in /usr/lib*/pm-utils/power.d/

CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'

for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done

if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE

    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi

exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/disable_wol] [executable]
#!/bin/sh
# tlp - if tlp is enabled, override corresponding script
#       in /usr/lib*/pm-utils/power.d/

CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'

for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done

if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE

    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi

exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/intel-audio-powersave] [executable]
#!/bin/sh
# tlp - if tlp is enabled, override corresponding script
#       in /usr/lib*/pm-utils/power.d/

CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'

for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done

if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE

    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi

exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/laptop-mode] [executable]
#!/bin/sh
# tlp - if tlp is enabled, override corresponding script
#       in /usr/lib*/pm-utils/power.d/

CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'

for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done

if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE

    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi

exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pci_devices] [executable]
#!/bin/sh
# tlp - if tlp is enabled, override corresponding script
#       in /usr/lib*/pm-utils/power.d/

CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'

for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done

if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE

    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi

exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pcie_aspm] [executable]
#!/bin/sh
# tlp - if tlp is enabled, override corresponding script
#       in /usr/lib*/pm-utils/power.d/

CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'

for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done

if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE

    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi

exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/sata_alpm] [executable]
#!/bin/sh
# tlp - if tlp is enabled, override corresponding script
#       in /usr/lib*/pm-utils/power.d/

CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'

for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done

if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE

    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi

exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/sched-powersave] [executable]
#!/bin/sh
# tlp - if tlp is enabled, override corresponding script
#       in /usr/lib*/pm-utils/power.d/

CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'

for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done

if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE

    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi

exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/usb_bluetooth] [executable]
#!/bin/sh
# tlp - if tlp is enabled, override corresponding script
#       in /usr/lib*/pm-utils/power.d/

CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'

for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done

if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE

    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi

exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/wireless] [executable]
#!/bin/sh
# tlp - if tlp is enabled, override corresponding script
#       in /usr/lib*/pm-utils/power.d/

CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'

for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done

if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE

    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi

exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/xfs_buffer] [executable]
#!/bin/sh
# tlp - if tlp is enabled, override corresponding script
#       in /usr/lib*/pm-utils/power.d/

CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'

for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done

if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE

    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi

exit 0


Kernel boot line ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-26-generic root=UUID=ecd4fcb4-3903-4d0d-9c55-67a896484dce ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7


dmesg ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[    0.028176] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.028184] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
[    0.930586] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[    0.931026] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    1.065059] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    1.072386] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[   14.256449] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: renamed from eth0
[   15.181573] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
[   15.211677] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   15.211871] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   27.279950] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   30.370164] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[ 1655.138824] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth7: link is not ready
[ 1655.589754] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1659.082089] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 1661.819691] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[ 1981.263541] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth7: link is not ready
[ 1981.263888] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1983.904584] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 1984.571833] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[ 2339.996563] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link up
[ 3286.781263] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[ 3295.163650] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth7: link is not ready
[ 3295.163958] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 3297.816675] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 3298.491933] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[ 3852.161857] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth7: link is not ready
[ 3852.162176] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 3853.709470] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 3854.376644] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[ 4662.605213] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link up
[ 5009.277309] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[ 5025.909797] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[ 5028.261141] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link up
[ 7531.592297] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[ 7533.717529] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 7535.301869] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 7535.316223] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[ 7538.169958] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth7: link is not ready
[ 7538.200005] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[11658.000439] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth7: link is not ready
[11658.000754] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[11660.064767] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[11660.731952] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[12950.478395] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link up
[25353.705109] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[25390.930943] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth7: link is not ready
[25390.931312] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[25393.547842] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[25394.207065] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link down
[25664.844432] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link up
[25664.854576] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth7: link up

    ======== Done ========
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf :

blacklist hp_wmi

You might have to restart.
if that doesn't work then try to reset the bios.