# HP 15 ab035ax with rtl8723be WiFi not working properly

Tags: realtek-wireless

HP 15 ab035ax with rtl8723be WiFi not working properly only sometimes and doesn't recognise WiFi card occasionally how do I make it work

Comment: Other people are having problems with  rtl8732be as well. That and the problem with HP may not be related. Please search the site for each problems separately. Then edit the question so that there is only one question asked in each question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Comment: @user68186 I have tried all the solutions including compiling lwfinger and the options file and none of them have worked though it seems to work for others, therefore suspect it may have to do with the laptop model

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593848/254422

Answer (score 1):

The following might be useful:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone [https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E.git][1]
cd MT7630E/
chmod +x install test uninstall
./install
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the code is doing. If it is building a kernel module what module and why it helps. Thanks for the solution by the way will try it out.

Comment: Am asking because my card is realtek rtl8723be.