# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS wifi disconnects/reconnects constantly

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop using USB alongside with Windows 10. But I'm having wifi issues under Ubuntu since then - it is disconnecting after some time after loading the system. I've used few advices from forums (without really understanding what they're for), and it made wifi reconnect after disconnecting and now it happens periodically. I'm using Lenovo Z50. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

This is an output of **$lspci -knn | grep Net -A2**:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]

    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

**EDIT2:**

This is what other queries return.

**$rfkill list**:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**$ifconfig && iwconfig && route -n && ping -c 1 google.com**:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:d2:44:9d:09:b7  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:3658 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3658 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:299662 (299.6 KB)  TX bytes:299662 (299.6 KB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:48:9a:57:64:cf  
      inet addr:192.168.100.3  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::9248:9aff:fe57:64cf/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:9725 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9115 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:8674056 (8.6 MB)  TX bytes:1594720 (1.5 MB)

eth0  no wireless extensions.

wlan0 IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"HUAWEI-I46k"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: F8:BF:09:87:03:7C   
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-32 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo    no wireless extensions.

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
PING google.com (64.233.165.101) 56(84) bytes of data.    
64 bytes from lg-in-f101.1e100.net (64.233.165.101): icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=56.2 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 56.216/56.216/56.216/0.000 ms
```

I guess the last query result may vary because, as I told, wifi connection is unstable and is not down all the time.

**EDIT3:**

```
rail@Rail-Ubuntu:~$ for p in /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/*; do echo $p; cat $p; done;
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/debug
0
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/disable_watchdog
N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/fwlps
Y
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/ips
Y
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/msi
N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/swenc
N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/swlps
N
```

**EDIT4**

I've reinstalled my system and now my wifi issue has changed: it is connected at the first ~5 minutes but then totally disconnects. I've followed some help tips and came to this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsRealTek

So, next questions are:

- I don't have file /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf, how could that happen and what can I do to make it there?
- "Last updated" column says update is on 10-11 (October 11th, I guess). What does that mean
- "Comments" field says it's for Ubuntu 15.04 while I'm using 14.04. Does this mean it is not applicable for my case?
- Maybe I should create new thread for that issue?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6, thank you for reply, here is the edit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Comment: @Pilot6, I followed your recommendations exactly, but it didn't help yet.

Comment: Did it install without errors?

Comment: By the way, I have no **rtl18723be.conf** in */etc/modprobe.d*

Comment: @Pilot6, yes it did install without errors, but all the symptomes are the same...

Comment: It works for most of the people. I have no better solution.

Comment: What encryption is the wireless network set for?  You can check `iwlist scan` and look for the group and pairwise ciphers under your ESSID

Comment: Please edit to include `for p in /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/*; do echo $p; cat $p; done` thanks

Comment: @Jeremy31, here is iwlist scan output ESSID values: ESSID:"DIR-300NRU"

Comment: @Jeremy31, I've added the output for 'for p in /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/* etc'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiFi disconnects for few seconds and resume](http://askubuntu.com/questions/730908/wifi-disconnects-for-few-seconds-and-resume)

Answer (score 0):

I would `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` and reboot

There was a [patch](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg139532.html) submitted that says disabling fwlps fixes a lot of disconnect issues.  The patch would make the `fwlps=N` the default value

Comment: That won't help if OP installed the driver from my ppa. It is set there already. I think he did not install it correctly.

Comment: @Pilot6  I was just wondering if you did change the code for that today, I do have another idea

Comment: @Jeremy31: you're losing it!  You're showing up in the low quality review queue!  **>:-)** (Voted "Looks OK")  **;-)**

Comment: @Pilot6, what do you mean by "install it correctly". Maybe you can explain the problem with drivers as whole so I can read more on the topic?