# Wireless Connection Dropping Frequently Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet, realtek

My Ubuntu 14.04 is finally installed on this dell emmc machine and the internet does work, but it drops after a few minutes of use (especially downloading).

Here's the link to my wireless_script run I found via the forums: http://pastebin.com/6qpFDLx3

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks,
Duff

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your access point is on channel 6 and your wireless_script reports:

> 31   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

I recommend that you change to channel 1.

Second, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Finally, I worked on a case a couple of weeks ago where connectivity was impossible because there were spaces in the name of the access point. Yours is named *Casa De Messi*. I suggest you experiment by changing it to *CasaDeMessi* or *Casa_De_Messi*, or some such.