# HP Pavillion ab011nx -wifi not working properly on ubuntu

Tags: wireless, hp-pavilion

I purchased a HP pavillion 15 ab011nx laptop with Windows 8.1 built in.The wifi works perfectly in windows but is really very weak in ubuntu that I can use wifi in lap only when I place lap very near to my modem.I tried to solve the issue with dkms rtl wifi commands shown in the results but still it is not working.Please help me find the correct solution.My ethernet too is not working.The details are as given below

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    DeviceName: Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11b/g/n 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804c]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Comment: @pilot6 Thanks for your help.But this solution is not working for ubuntu 16.04.Please suggest a solution

Comment: `ant_sel` setting should fix this.

Comment: most of the solutions with ant_sel didnt work.Precisely the command used to set ant_sel is not working with me.Can you provide me any precise link to fix using ant_sel

Comment: The fix is in the link I already gave.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback..Finally,disabling secure boot helped

Comment: The same issue came once again after I upgraded to 16.10.Please help me with a solution

Comment: It was not the best idea to upgrade to 16.10. I do not support non-LTS versions in my PPA. Maybe I will, maybe I won't.

Comment: Is there any way to come back to 16.04 without re-installing?

Comment: No, you need to re-install.