# Wifi realtek Realtek 8723BE inoperative on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, realtek, realtek-wireless

I've just purchased a notebook lenovo b50-80, mate ubuntu 15.10 installation with bios in legacy mode

I made several attempts to operate the card by following this guide: [How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem); 
and this procedure that i found here: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/28#issuecomment-172619447 :

```
git clone git://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
git checkout rock.new_btcoex
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot. After the system comes up:

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

Now test. If that still does not work, then try

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

I also tried to enter several parameters in `rtl8723be.conf` but nothing ... 
the most i obtained was a short connection after a reboot (3-4 min) followed by disconnection and lack of networks in the Network panel.

the output is:

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

This is the output of rfkill command:

```
maria@maria-Lenovo-B50-80:~$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Did you run this commands one by one, or like you typed them?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: yes i run this commands one by one, now i'll post the output,

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i posted the output of your command, now what i have to do?

Comment: Please post the exact command `Net` should start with a capital `N`.

Comment: 09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723] (rev ff)
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: And also please post output of `rfkill list`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make some mistakes when installing the drivers.

I packed them to PPA, it is easier to install. Run these commands (carefully, one by one):

```
cd rtlwifi_new
sudo make uninstall
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

Then reboot and test. Maybe you will need `ant_sel` parameter. Maybe not.

Comment: ndiswrapper is obsolete. It needs WindowsXP drivers. But some work with linux well, but I do not track them.

Comment: I got this one to use instead of that realtek crap on my hp, works great, been streaming something 24/7 for over a week, no issues, no drops http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00EQT0YK2?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s00

Comment: ok i try to reinstall ubuntu and repeat your procedure, then if don't work i will install windows...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35629/discussion-on-answer-by-pilot6-wifi-realtek-realtek-8723be-inoperative-on-ubuntu).