# (32) insufficient privileges

Tags: 14.04, networking, permissions

I'm getting an error called `(32) insufficient privileges` while trying to connect to my wifi network. The existing solutions don't seem to work.

```
bhagirath@bhagirath-HP-ProBook-440-G2:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you try to connect?

Comment: Generally it is an automatic connection. otherwise i go to topleft corner of the desktop, tap the netwrk connections and then select my netwrks manually, however after trying one of the solutions which involved 'pkill nm-applet', i lost the symbol completely and could not retrieve it back. Ultimately i had to reinstall the entire OS

Comment: And what happened after you re-installed the OS?

Comment: Initially i was able to provide my wifi network while installation, however eventually, now it is failing to reconnect.

Comment: I thought it must be a kernel issue or a drivers issue as one of my previous problems dealt with the same problem, I tried to install all updates using sudo apt-get install update and upgrade commands. This could not finish entirely as the final message read certain packages could not be installed due to lack of access.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: You run a wrong command.

Comment: Please use a "dash" (key right of the 0) and not  another char.

Comment: He used `~` instead of `|`.

Comment: Apologies however my keyboard for some reason is not typing  ' | '. I endup typing tilde wen I press the same on Ubuntu.

Comment: Solved the prob. Dead keys! posting the output for the asked command

Comment: i re -edited my question with the appropriate output! please which way to proceed.

Comment: Please instruct me further @Pilot6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Comment: I edited the question again with new results @Pilot6.

Comment: Hey it seems like it worked. although I request you to tell me why such a  problem came. despite regular updates why is it tht drivers are causing problem. there was an earlier question by me regarding wifi problem where you suggested a kernel problem and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following instructions, give them a shot

- `pkill nm-applet`
- then become root
- start nm-applet
- set up connection and check "Available to all users."
- Kill nm-applet again
- Exit root
- start nm-applet as a normal user

Source: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=21636

Comment: wat exactly do u mean by 'then become root' plz give me specific instructions.

Comment: It did not work.