# ubuntu 14.04 LTS wifi problem

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I'm new to ubuntu and i have installed the 14.04LTS version 2 days ago,But i have a wifi problem ! when i turn one the laptop and get started everything works fine and the connection is good but not for a long time it's just about 5 minutes and i lose the networking, Everything looks to be good and working i have no disconnection error or any sign it just loses the networking i can't open any site or do anything just like it's disconnected,
I have tried to disconnect it and connect again but when i do that it never connects again " Disconnected , you are offline " ,
All i can do to connect to the internet is to use a wired connection or to restart my laptop again :/ I'm really tired and starting to regret installing ubuntu , i tried alot of things on this site or other sites about the terminal command lines but it's still the same, So please someone help me !

this is my wifi info :

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 27 Feb 2016 10:33 EET +0200

Booted last: 27 Feb 2016 09:00 EET +0200

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.2.0-30-generic #35~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 14:48:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380b]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 174f:14b2 Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 046d:c016 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rndis_wlan             57344  0 
rndis_host             16384  1 rndis_wlan
usbnet                 40960  3 rndis_host,rndis_wlan,cdc_ether
rtl8723be              90112  0 
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              729088  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
cfg80211              540672  3 mac80211,rndis_wlan,rtlwifi
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          200704  1 snd_soc_rt5640
ideapad_laptop         24576  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
snd_pcm               102400  8 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
video                  40960  3 i915,ideapad_laptop,nouveau
wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'usb0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.42.132  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'usb0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:86095 errors:7 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:7
          TX packets:72237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:83388892 (83.3 MB)  TX bytes:11985551 (11.9 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9909 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7625 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11767106 (11.7 MB)  TX bytes:1353364 (1.3 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       838     1  0 09:00 ?        00:00:01 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: usb0  [Wired connection 2] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            rndis_host
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'usb0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.42.132
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.42.129

    DNS:             192.168.42.129

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8723be
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

Sorry, try again.
[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ro_ma]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ro_ma | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ro_ma | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HUAWEI-97d6]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HUAWEI-97d6 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=HUAWEI-97d6 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ppmu]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ppmu | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ppmu | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Africa/Cairo (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

usb0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'mayar saad' [AC1]>
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=34/70  Signal level=-76 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"mayar saad"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000a8684e17e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 812ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'ppmu' [AC2]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-34 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ppmu"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000036dec7157
                    Extra: Last beacon: 172ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'ro_ma' [AC3]>
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ro_ma"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000db6c2b15b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1508ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     0EB6BE33DFAD6AEFD4D63AE
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        A5:12:3B:D7:BC:9F:40:9E:55:8B:C8:E5:DE:0B:BB:59:AA:18:40:1F
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     251C540A2D3AD38CCA85ED9
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        A5:12:3B:D7:BC:9F:40:9E:55:8B:C8:E5:DE:0B:BB:59:AA:18:40:1F
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     2E1C688267DE11E1F26A728
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        A5:12:3B:D7:BC:9F:40:9E:55:8B:C8:E5:DE:0B:BB:59:AA:18:40:1F
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     F4CACC5FCAEBE7C22930A24
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        A5:12:3B:D7:BC:9F:40:9E:55:8B:C8:E5:DE:0B:BB:59:AA:18:40:1F
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     292BCC26A10EA884DF6B5FF
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        A5:12:3B:D7:BC:9F:40:9E:55:8B:C8:E5:DE:0B:BB:59:AA:18:40:1F
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     7982686FBE8064A87E02753
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        A5:12:3B:D7:BC:9F:40:9E:55:8B:C8:E5:DE:0B:BB:59:AA:18:40:1F
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723be]
debug: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
msi: N
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf]
options rtl8723be fwl=0

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x10ec:0xb723 (rtl8723be)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
# USB device 0x:0x (cdc_ether)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

##### dmesg #############################

[ 3572.727341] usb 1-3: device firmware changed
[ 5568.365431] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'ppmu' [AC2]>
[ 5568.388846] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC 'ppmu' [AC2]> (try 1/3)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Comment: I would check the logs for anything relating to WiFi. Type "dmesg | more" from a terminal, use space bar to show a new page, <ctrl>'C to abort.