# Can't connect to WIFI Access Point in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (14.04). I have my WIFI driver installed properly. When my computer starts, and if an Access Point is saved, it will connect to it. It works fine for 5 miutes or so before it stops working (WIFI AP stays connected but does not connect to the internet). And then if I disconnect from the WIFI and connect again, it won't connect at all. So WIFI APs only get connected on startup and stop working after a few minutes.

Can anyone help me on this?

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Okay will do  @Pilot6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this: `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

And then this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

Viola! Reboot and done!