# WiFi connects to router but internet connection drops

Tags: wireless

I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 but I am having issues with my WiFi where it'll connect to the router but sometimes the internet connection will drop and I do not know why.

I have a HP computer with an i7.

```
hp@hp-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Does this happen to other devices on the same network? It may not be an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score -1):

Check to see if you have more than one kernel installed and try booting from an different one.

If you have only one kernel installed, check for upgrades, if one is available, install it, then reboot.