# Wi-Fi connected, but drops after a while (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, internet

I have to admit that i'm not expert in Linux or technology in general, so excuse me for the stupid question. 
Some weeks ago I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my Lenovo z50-70. Since than i'm experiencing wifi issues: it shows that the pc is connected, but after a while it doesn't work at all. I have to disconnect/reconnect to make it work again, and this happens every 15-20 minutes (now i'm using a TP-Link modem).

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network 
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
physical id: 0 
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0 
logical name: enp1s0 
version: 10 
serial: 68:f7:28:87:a9:98 
size: 10Mbit/s 
capacity: 1Gbit/s 
width: 64 bits 
clock: 33MHz 
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation 
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s 
resources: irq:45 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:c3504000-c3504fff memory:c3500000-c3503fff 

*-network
description: Wireless interface 
product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter 
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
physical id: 0 
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0 
logical name: wlp2s0 
version: 00 
serial: 2c:33:7a:4b:78:5b 
width: 64 bits 
clock: 33MHz 
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.2.0-34-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.111 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn 
resources: irq:19 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c3400000-c3403fff

$ iwconfig
wlp2s0 IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID:"Tiscali"
Mode:Managed Frequency:2.412 GHz Access Point: E8:94:F6:0F:AB:8D 
Bit Rate=15 Mb/s Tx-Power=20 dBm 
Retry short limit:7 RTS thr=2347 B Fragment thr:off Power Management:off Link Quality=56/70 Signal level=-54 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0 Tx excessive retries:0 Invalid misc:18 Missed beacon:0 lo no wireless extensions. enp1s0 no wireless extensions.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)