# HP 15 AC179TX - WiFi not working after Ubuntu Installation

Tags: iwlwifi

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on my new laptop HP 15 AC179TX.
I could not see any WiFi networks detected. I could SEE the option "Enable WiFi". But after turn on also none of the network is getting discovered. In my other laptop I could see the near by all networks.

One more interesting thing is the WiFi network from mobile hotspot is discovered. Only the WiFi signals from router is not discovered. This is weird but this is what happening.

Please assist me on how to fix it.

Below is the Wireless-info collected from the system.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 16 Apr 2016 21:07 IST +0530

Booted last: 16 Apr 2016 17:54 IST +0530

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8136]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05c8:0382 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 14cd:125d Super Top 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
rtl8723be              90112  0 
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              729088  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
iwlwifi               204800  0 
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
cfg80211              540672  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,rtlwifi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.43.74  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'wlan0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:70 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:33391 (33.3 KB)  TX bytes:25713 (25.7 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"AndroidAP"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:29   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       824     1  0 17:54 ?        00:00:01 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [AndroidAP] ---------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8723be
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           72 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    *AndroidAP:      Infra, <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 46 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.43.74
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.43.1

    DNS:             192.168.43.1

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ptEHXgAAAAAAAwHgSundeep 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ptEHXgAAAAAAAwHgSundeep 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ptEHXgAAAAAAAwHgSundeep | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AndroidAP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=AndroidAP | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=AndroidAP | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ptEHXgAAAAAAAwHgSundeep]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ptEHXgAAAAAAAwHgSundeep | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ptEHXgAAAAAAAwHgSundeep | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=26/70  Signal level=-84 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"AndroidAP"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000000229512a
                    Extra: Last beacon: 60ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     F4844EEE911CB18A8B2934B
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     251C540A2D3AD38CCA85ED9
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     A888EFDC516033207A503FA
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     F4CACC5FCAEBE7C22930A24
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     FBF6EA073A00B4F3836226E
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-12.ucode
srcversion:     75997E53B9CC3BD2CA79F3B
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     7982686FBE8064A87E02753
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:6E:2F:9E:A1:B4:72:8A:15:AC:16:9B:18:69:26:7E:11:28:D6:E8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723be]
debug: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
msi: N
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc
iwlwifi

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x10ec:0xb723 (rtl8723be)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[  217.871815] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[  217.871818] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[  217.871845] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin failed with error -2
[  217.871848] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[  220.185321] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link down
[  220.185377] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  220.405619] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link down
[  220.405678] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  233.295995] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 2562.692831] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]>
[ 2562.713957] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 2562.719497] wlan0: authenticated
[ 2562.723769] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 2562.743411] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]> (capab=0x8431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 2562.744318] wlan0: associated
[ 2562.744331] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Comment: **Procedure in this link solves my problem.**
[http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)