# Looking for wifi drivers for Hp 250 g4 for ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, realtek, realtek-wireless

As I have purchased new hp 250 g4 laptop and when I tried to install WiFi drivers its taking other drivers but not working fine.

most of the time it doesn't connected only to my WiFi device and also if it get connected also then there is a issue related to speed.

I spoke to the customer care of HP and they said that you need to update the WiFi drivers. `Realtek RTL8723BE/RTL8188EE 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN drivers`.

Please help me from where I can get this drivers.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Comment: @Imran Khatri : did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

You need to update, for which you'll need to use an ethernet cable or wifi dongle that works with Linux out of the box.

Once you've updated you can simple paste this into the terminal and press enter:

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1 fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

If you're asked for your password, enter it and press enter. Now reset your laptop and it should work. If it doesn't, try all the steps above again but this time change `ant_sel=1` to `ant_sel=2`.

### Details

The problem is that the wifi hardware only has one of the two antennas attached but the hardware reports the wrong antenna. So you need to force the driver to use the correct antenna, which can only be done with the newer driver. To see if your driver supports this option, open a terminal and do:

```
modinfo rtl8723be
```

If it has the output has the line:

```
parm:           ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)
 (int)
```

Then you have the updated driver. If not then you will need to update using an ethernet cable or wifi dongle to get internet access.

Once you have the right drivers you need to force it to use the right antenna, like so:

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1 fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

And then reset the laptop. If this does not work then try the above again but change `ant_sel=1` to `ant_sel=2`.

The `fwlps=N` prevents an issue where power saving would drop the connection after a time even when being used.

**16.04 note**: You can temporarily try different antenna settings before permanently setting configuration by reloading the driver using the following:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

This will allow you to make sure it works without having to reset the laptop each time.

Comment: There is no need to upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried it with 14.04 installed. Once update it does have the right driver option but I still was unable to connect even when sitting right next to the access point.

Comment: You can use the same `ant_sel` switch. This is the same driver.

Comment: @Pilot6 Huh... I just tried again and it does work if I edit the conf file and reset but the modprobe commands don't work for some reason.  I'll edit my answer.