# Make doesn't work

Tags: networking, kubuntu, rtl8723be

I use a network card called the `rtl8723be`. In Ubuntu, that card randomly halts every ten to twenty minutes and my network manager doesn't detect it. There is a solution. A guy named lwfinger put some drivers on github and they work great. Unfortunately, I recently switched to Kubuntu 14.04 and when I try to make the drivers I get this error code:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/build M=/home/liam/rtlwifi_new modules make[1]: Entering directory /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:123: stack-protector enabled but compiler support broken
arch/x86/Makefile:138: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:662: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR: -fstack-protector not supported by compiler
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
  CC [M]  /home/liam/rtlwifi_new/base.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
make[2]: *** [/home/liam/rtlwifi_new/base.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/liam/rtlwifi_new] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic' make: * [all] Error 2 make -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/build M=/home/liam/rtlwifi_new modules make[1]: Entering directory /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:123: stack-protector enabled but compiler support broken
arch/x86/Makefile:138: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:662: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR: -fstack-protector not supported by compiler
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
  CC [M]  /home/liam/rtlwifi_new/base.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
make[2]: *** [/home/liam/rtlwifi_new/base.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/liam/rtlwifi_new] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic' make: * [all] Error 2
```

If you know a solution, please let me know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the Gnu Compiler Collection. It can be installed along with other necessary build tools with the meta-package `build-essential`:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!