# Rosewill wireless card dropping bandwidth, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless

I bought a Rosewill RNX-N250PCe - Wireless N300 Wi-Fi Adapter for my desktop, running Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm getting about a third the number of Mbps as my laptop.

Using lspci -v, I get that the wireless card is:
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter.

Does anyone know how I can get back the other two thirds of my bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

Try this post:

[How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Remember to replace rtl8723be with yours configuration.

Run  "sudo lshw -C network" in terminal to know correct configuration.

Comment: This added 17Mbps (36 to 53), but still not reaching full capacity (90).

Comment: Nevermind, I think it was a fluke.