# Bluetooth not responding 16.04

Tags: bluetooth

My bluetooth is not responding again:

I Got this:

```
javier@JavUBU:~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    1.785223] usb 3-4: Product: RT Bluetooth Radio
[   19.167891] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   19.167911] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   19.167914] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   19.167916] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   19.167920] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   19.433162] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b    lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
[   19.433165] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
[   20.317761] Bluetooth: hci0: download fw command failed (-19)
[   31.973710] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   31.973714] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   31.973717] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

But the service seems up and running:

```
javier@JavUBU:~$ journalctl -b |grep -i bluetooth
Jun 12 11:11:25 JavUBU kernel: usb 3-4: Product: RT Bluetooth Radio
Jun 12 11:11:35 JavUBU kernel: Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
Jun 12 11:11:35 JavUBU kernel: Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Jun 12 11:11:35 JavUBU kernel: Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Jun 12 11:11:35 JavUBU kernel: Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Jun 12 11:11:35 JavUBU kernel: Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Jun 12 11:11:35 JavUBU kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
Jun 12 11:11:35 JavUBU kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
Jun 12 11:11:36 JavUBU kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: download fw command failed (-19)
Jun 12 11:11:40 JavUBU systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jun 12 11:11:42 JavUBU bluetoothd[938]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
Jun 12 11:11:46 JavUBU systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 12 11:11:46 JavUBU systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Jun 12 11:11:46 JavUBU systemd[1]: bluetooth.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Jun 12 11:11:46 JavUBU systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Jun 12 11:11:46 JavUBU bluetoothd[938]: Starting SDP server
Jun 12 11:11:48 JavUBU kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Jun 12 11:11:48 JavUBU kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Jun 12 11:11:48 JavUBU kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Jun 12 11:11:48 JavUBU bluetoothd[938]: Bluetooth management interface 1.10 initialized
Jun 12 11:11:57 JavUBU NetworkManager[1078]: <info>  [1465722717.4383] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)

javier@JavUBU:~$ systemctl status bluetooth
 ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2016-06-12 11:11:46 CEST; 8min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 938 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 1.7M
      CPU: 10ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─938 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jun 12 11:11:40 JavUBU systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jun 12 11:11:42 JavUBU bluetoothd[938]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
Jun 12 11:11:46 JavUBU systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 12 11:11:46 JavUBU bluetoothd[938]: Starting SDP server
Jun 12 11:11:48 JavUBU bluetoothd[938]: Bluetooth management interface 1.10 init
```

Any help is very welcome

Javier

Comment: I had a solution for previous Ubuntu versions, but on 16.04 it is supposed to work out of the box. But it does not seem to be the case. See http://askubuntu.com/a/635629/167850