# WIFI poor signal HP 15-af165sa

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, broadcom, proxy

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804a]
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 36
Region 0: Memory at f0c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Wi-fi signal is really weak  but in the same time my mac signal is really strong . So it made me wonder that there is something wrong with the driver. I'm new here and with Linux in general as I never faced such issue I am really confused now . I had a similar issue with 16.04 and when tried to fix it , I managed to completely screw it up. so I reinstalled OS to 14.04.
I followed step by step here [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) and the signal has gone weaker than before and it keeps disconnecting even more often now.

Network diagnostics results : 
[results](https://gist.github.com/DavyMorzJones/e9449fbb9a3662200fc9b67391b5b966)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)  HP has been known to only use one antenna wire on a wifi card with 2 antenna connectors, the ant_sel parameter is the key to fixing it

Comment: What is the point of using a Realtek solution for a Broadcom adapter?

Comment: This may not be a duplicate as the original poster has a Broadcom adapter and not a Realtek adapter.

Comment: DavyJones: Please keep in mind that you should not delete and then re-ask old questions. In the future, if you wish to have a closed question of yours reopened, please make an edit or comment to your question containing your reasoning as to why it is not a duplicate, and flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @ThomasW. will do in future

Comment: @Pilot6 Any assistance with this issue ?

Comment: I have no solution for this issue, sry.

Comment: @Pilot6 I read that Broadcom module is not the best module for Linux system in general. So if there won't be any solution for this, I gonna have to change it I guess. Any Idea what would be the best option if i decide to change it? I was mac user for quite some time just because I'm not big fan of windows and wasn't really impressed with MacBook neither as it's not worth the money. I rather learn ubuntu instead of going back to win/mac .

Comment: New Intel adapters work well. I replaced mine to 7260ac. It works like a charm. 7265, or 8260 will do.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thank you. Any idea how to authenticate proxy?

Comment: You can find an answer about apt and proxy.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly, absolutely not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

After these things are done, reboot and test. Give us your report. If the issue is not improved, please let us have an updated *wireless_script*.