# Wifi occasionally stops working on Lenovo ideapad 100 laptop with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I purchased a new Lenovo ideapad 100 laptop back in February.  A couple of days ago I formatted the hard-drive and replaced the original operating system, Windows 10, with Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

Most things are working fine but the wifi occasionally stops working.  When I try to install gimp from the ubuntu software centre and apache from apt-get in the terminal it always stops working and I have to restart the computer to get it back.  It also stopped working when I tried posting this question here.

The output to `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`  is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.   RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:b728]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: disable secure boot and try again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a Lenovo ideapad 300:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
```

Modifying the drivers and settings made no difference. I spent almost a week on this. In the end, installing wicd fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It stops working or it not detects other wifi networks?
If the second (like my lenovo does) the only think i found is restarting the following service

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
sudo service network-manager restart
```