# Wifi is constantly turning off

Tags: wireless, laptop

I am using Lenovo B50-45 laptop.

Results of `iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp6s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Clap Along"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 70:54:D2:58:CC:0F   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-26 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:72   Missed beacon:0
```

Results of `ifconfig`:

```
enp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:76:1c:12:e4:ee  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2377 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2377 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:215879 (215.8 KB)  TX bytes:215879 (215.8 KB)

wlp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b0:10:41:cb:4f:25  
          inet addr:192.168.0.15  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a3c8:64a0:aa35:762/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12338 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9531921 (9.5 MB)  TX bytes:1776864 (1.7 MB)
```

Result of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:b736]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

Pastebin result of Wireless script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17993626/

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem