# WiFi / Ethernet connection on RTL8101 & RTL8723BE drops repeatedly every 5 - 10 seconds

Tags: 14.04, wireless, ethernet

My LAN / Ethernet and WiFi are not working properly in Ubuntu 14.04.

LAN is connected but net got disconnected in 5 to 10 seconds repeatedly and it is not problem of net because it is working fine on another laptop.

output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'`:

```
08:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 804c
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8096
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Comment: This is the Wi-Fi solution. Ethernet is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but downloading WICD decreased the frequency of network problems I experienced when I was using lubuntu.

Comment: but if i do that then i have to uninstall network manager and it is possible that if wicd does not work then how will i configure the net.