# WiFi stopped working after sometime 14.04 LTS on HP laptop

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and my laptop WiFi stopped working after some time. It remains stopped until I reboot my system.

Command:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

Output:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

On terminal type this command

```
rfkill unblock all
```

This will help you if you have soft blocks on your network interface

If it doesn't work try these

`ifup`  This command will bring your network interface up.Run this as your root by specifying your network interface

If you don't know your name of your network interface try this command  `ifconfig -a`

Comment: Nothing blocked:rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Try with that it may help you

Comment: @GovindSamrow: Please [edit] your post, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.