# D-Link 2750U Wi-Fi Router Not showing in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, d-link

This is my First Question in the form.

I have an hp-ac122tu laptop with realtek NIC.

I can connect to all Wi-Fi routers and my Android hot-spot without any problem( Except Network manager won't refresh until restart). But this particular Wi-Fi modem is not being detected by Ubuntu and Other Linux distro while my WIndows 10 and all other devices can connect to it hassle free.

Now How do I fix it? Any helping hand is appreciated.

Right now I'm using Wi-Fi by tethering my Android device.

```
~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Install this driver http://askubuntu.com/a/635629/167850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since not being able to get a proper solution from here I went on and took the risk of downloading a driver from gitub and manually installing my realtek driver.

type this in your terminal window

$ iwconfig

and found out my wifi's name. wlp13s0

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/tree/rock.new_btcoex

went to this link and downloaded the zip file (clone).
put it in the desktop and change directory using commands

$ cd Desktop

and extracted the file on desktop

$ cd rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex

$ make && sudo make install && sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be && sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2 && sudo ip link set wlp13s0 up

THe last command is supposed to turn n wifi so just in case it doesn't work , manually turn on the Wi-Fi

and

$ sudo iw dev wlp13s0 scan

and THere my Wi-Fi hotspot name was listed.

$ echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d
/50-rtl8723be.conf

to save the current configurations into the file.

Restarted my system. and Wi-Fi is normal and working all well.

another way is to change the tx power which is risky so I skipped.

In case anyone have the same problem with realtek linux drivers, follow these steps.

Note: For installing it in kali linux you will need to have latest kali release and kernel.

Comment: This is the same driver I suggested in comments.