# Ubuntu 14.04 - wireless issue after update

Tags: wireless

I have updated my system recently and have not more wifi. Could you please help me out to repair this ?

```
lspci -nn gives this: 

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1503] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1c14] (rev b4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1c18] (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c49] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 04)
01:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller [1180:e823] (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:0091] (rev 34)
03:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 04)
```

```
lshw -C Network
 *-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 19
       information bus: pci@0000:00:19.0
       nom logique: eth0
       version: 04
       numéro de série: e8:e0:b7:5a:d4:50
       taille: 1Gbit/s
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 32 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.0.16 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       ressources: irq:46 mémoire:c0700000-c071ffff mémoire:c072b000-c072bfff portE/S:2080(taille=32)
  *-network NON-RÉCLAMÉ
       description: Network controller
       produit: Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak]
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 34
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       ressources: mémoire:c0500000-c0501fff
```

Thank you

```
uname -r; dpkg -l | grep extra
3.13.0-95-generic
ii  binfmt-support                                        2.1.4-1                                             i386         Support for extra binary formats
ii  cabextract                                            1.4-4                                               i386         Microsoft Cabinet file unpacker
ii  cdparanoia                                            3.10.2+debian-11                                    i386         audio extraction tool for sampling CDs
ii  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra                          52.0.2743.116-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1134                 i386         Extra ffmpeg codecs for the Chromium Browser
ii  fonts-dejavu                                          2.34-1ubuntu1                                       all          metapackage to pull in fonts-dejavu-core and fonts-dejavu-extra
ii  fonts-dejavu-extra                                    2.34-1ubuntu1                                       all          Vera font family derivate with additional characters (extra variants)
ii  gnome-themes-extras                                   2.22.0-3                                            all          extra themes for the GNOME desktop
ii  icoutils                                              0.31.0-2                                            i386         Create and extract MS Windows icons and cursors
ii  libarchive-extract-perl                               0.70-1                                              all          generic archive extracting module
rc  libavcodec-extra-53:i386                              4:0.8.12ubuntu0.12.04.1                             i386         Libav codec library
ii  libavcodec-extra-54:i386                              6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             i386         Libav codec library (additional codecs)
rc  libavutil-extra-51:i386                               4:0.8.12ubuntu0.12.04.1                             i386         Libav utility library
ii  libcdparanoia0:i386                                   3.10.2+debian-11                                    i386         audio extraction tool for sampling CDs (library)
ii  libgnomevfs2-extra:i386                               1:2.24.4-1ubuntu6                                   i386         GNOME Virtual File System (extra modules)
ii  libgnuinet-java                                       1.1.2-2build1                                       all          extension library to provide extra network protocol support
ii  libhtml-tableextract-perl                             2.11-1                                              all          module for extracting the content contained in HTML tables
ii  libido-0.1-0:i386                                     12.10.0.1-0ubuntu2                                  i386         Shared library providing extra gtk menu items for display in
ii  libido3-0.1-0:i386                                    13.10.0+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1                     i386         Shared library providing extra gtk menu items for display in
ii  libmagickcore5-extra:i386                             8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.1                               i386         low-level image manipulation library - extra codecs
ii  liborbit2:i386                                        1:2.14.19-0.3                                       i386         high-performance CORBA implementation - extra libraries
ii  libpurple-bin                                         1:2.10.9-0ubuntu3.3                                 all          multi-protocol instant messaging library - extra utilities
ii  librsvg2-common:i386                                  2.40.2-1                                            i386         SAX-based renderer library for SVG files (extra runtime)
ii  libvcdinfo0                                           0.7.24+dfsg-0.1ubuntu2                              i386         library to extract information from VideoCD
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-37-generic                   3.13.0-37.64                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic                   3.13.0-39.66                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic                   3.13.0-40.69                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic                   3.13.0-43.72                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic                   3.13.0-45.74                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic                   3.13.0-46.79                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic                   3.13.0-48.80                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic                   3.13.0-58.97                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic                   3.13.0-63.103                                       i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic                   3.13.0-65.106                                       i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  oxideqt-codecs-extra:i386                             1.9.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                              i386         Web browser engine library for Qt (codecs)
ii  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin:i386   0.23+14.04.20140428-0ubuntu1                        i386         Ubuntu web browser QML plugin
ii  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin-assets 0.23+14.04.20140428-0ubuntu1                        all          Ubuntu web browser QML plugin assets
ii  ttf-dejavu-extra                                      2.34-1ubuntu1                                       all          transitional dummy package
ii  ubuntu-extras-keyring                                 2010.09.27                                          all          GnuPG keys of the Ubuntu extras archive
ii  ubuntu-restricted-extras                              60.1                                                i386         Commonly used restricted packages for Ubuntu
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/826257/edit) your question to include results from `uname -r; dpkg -l | grep extra` Thanks

Comment: Do you have secure boot enabled in your BIOS? You might turn it off and see if that helps your problems. Also, do you have `intel-microcode` and `linux-firmware` installed? Cheers, Al

Comment: I installed the package but it did not resolve the issue.
Requested input in initial post.

Comment: When I start from kernel 2.6, my wifi is enabled. Is it kernel related then ?

Answer (score 0):

I was Having the Similar problem.
But I followed these simple Instructions and now its solved.
Follow this [How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

**But carefully..!!**