# Wifi not seen not stable

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

I am using a HP laptop with windows dual boot. Moved to Ubuntu 3 days back. Not able to see my home wifi network (SSID) and if I see sometimes, the connection is not stable.

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
```

I have now edited the rtl8723be.conf files to have these following 3 options but no avail

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf 
options rtl8723be fwlps=0
options rtl8723be msi=1
options rtl8723be nohwcrypt=1
```

Someone please help, I won't be able to use Ubuntu without this feature

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu 16.04, please take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/847392/wlan-rtl8723be-frequently-disconnects for a possible solution

Comment: I tried it didnt work, it frequently disconnects, even settings->network shows the wifi is out of range, whereas for any other device it works perfectly well