# AFTER DISABILING SECURE BOOT FOR "WIFI NOT WORKING"

Tags: networking, drivers

After disabling Secure Boot, I gained back the info about "wlp" and also the "Enable Wifi" reappeared. Below is the info for some commands:

```
mayur@mayur-HP-Notebook:/media/mayur/New Volume$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
```

0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723] (rev ff)
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Kernel modules: rtl8723be
mayur@mayur-HP-Notebook:/media/mayur/New Volume$

mayur@mayur-HP-Notebook:/media/mayur/New Volume$ lshw
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  mayur-hp-notebook
  description: Computer
  width: 64 bits
  capabilities: vsyscall32
*-core
    description: Motherboard
    physical id: 0
*-memory
    description: System memory
    physical id: 0
    size: 3865MiB
*-cpu
    product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz
    vendor: Intel Corp.
    physical id: 1
    bus info: cpu@0
    size: 806MHz
    capacity: 1900MHz
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep 
                  mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 
                  ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc 
                  arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc 
                  aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 
                  ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe 
                  popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm 
                  abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority 
                  ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid 
                  rdseed adx smap xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts cpufreq
*-pci
     description: Host bridge
     product: Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 100
     bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
     version: 09
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     configuration: driver=bdw_uncore
     resources: irq:0
*-display
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
     version: 09
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
     configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
     resources: irq:45 memory:c2000000-c2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff 
     ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
*-multimedia:0
     description: Audio device
     product: Broadwell-U Audio Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 3
     bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
     version: 09
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
     resources: irq:48 memory:c5218000-c521bfff
*-generic:0 
     description: Signal processing controller
     product: Broadwell-U Camarillo Device
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 4
     bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
     version: 09
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
     resources: irq:16 memory:c5210000-c5217fff
*-usb 
     description: USB controller
     product: Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 14
     bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
     version: 03
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
     resources: irq:42 memory:c5200000-c520ffff
*-communication
     description: Communication controller
     product: Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 16
     bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
     version: 03
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
     resources: irq:47 memory:c5221000-c522101f
*-multimedia:1
     description: Audio device
     product: Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1b
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
     version: 03
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
     resources: irq:46 memory:c521c000-c521ffff
*-pci:0
     description: PCI bridge
     product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1c
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
     version: e3
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=pcieport
     resources: irq:16 ioport:5000(size=4096) memory:c6000000-c6ffffff 
     ioport:c0000000(size=16777216)
*-pci:1 
     description: PCI bridge
     product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1c.2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
     version: e3
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=pcieport
     resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:c4000000-c50fffff 
     ioport:c5100000(size=1048576)
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
     vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
     logical name: enp7s0
     version: 07
     serial: b0:5a:da:9d:ff:2f
     size: 10Mbit/s
     capacity: 100Mbit/s
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 
     100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 
     driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 
     latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
     resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c5000000-c5000fff 
     memory:c5100000-c5103fff
*-pci:2
     description: PCI bridge
     product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1c.5
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
     version: e3
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=pcieport
     resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:c3000000-c3ffffff 
     ioport:c1000000(size=16777216)
*-generic
      description: Wireless interface
      product: Illegal Vendor ID
      vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
      logical name: wlp13s0
      version: ff
      serial: 18:4f:32:2a:16:01
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 66MHz
      capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
      configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.10.0-28-
                     generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 
                    mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
      resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3000000-c3003fff
*-isa
     description: ISA bridge
     product: Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1f
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
     version: 03
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
*-storage
     description: SATA controller
     product: Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1f.2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
     version: 03
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 66MHz
     capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
     resources: irq:44 ioport:6088(size=8) ioport:6094(size=4) 
                ioport:6080(size=8) ioport:6090(size=4) ioport:6060(size=32) 
                memory:c5224000-c52247ff
*-serial UNCLAIMED
     description: SMBus
     product: Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1f.3
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3 
     version: 03
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:c5220000-c52200ff ioport:6040(size=32)
*-generic:1
     description: Signal processing controller
     product: Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1f.6
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
     version: 03
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
     resources: irq:18 memory:c5223000-c5223fff
*-scsi:0
     physical id: 2
     logical name: scsi1
     capabilities: emulated
*-cdrom
     description: DVD-RAM writer
     product: DVDRW GUB0N
     vendor: hp
     physical id: 0.0.0
     bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
     logical name: /dev/cdrom
     logical name: /dev/cdrw
     logical name: /dev/dvd
     logical name: /dev/dvdrw
     logical name: /dev/sr0
     version: UB00
     capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
     configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
*-scsi:1
     physical id: 3
     bus info: usb@1:1
     logical name: scsi2
     capabilities: emulated scsi-host
     configuration: driver=usb-storage
*-cdrom
     description: SCSI CD-ROM
     physical id: 0.0.0
     bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
     logical name: /dev/sr1
     logical name: /media/mayur/CDROM
     capabilities: audio
     configuration:mount.fstype=iso9660mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 state=mounted status=ready

WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
mayur@mayur-HP-Notebook:/media/mayur/New Volume$

mayur@mayur-HP-Notebook:/media/mayur/New Volume$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
wlp13s0   IEEE 802.11 ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated
          Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7
          RTS thr=2347 B
          Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
enp7s0    no wireless extensions.
mayur@mayur-HP-Notebook:/media/mayur/New Volume$ ifconfig
enp7s0   Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr b0:5a:da:9d:ff:2f
         UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
         RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo       Link encap:Local Loopback
         inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
         inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
         UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
         RX packets:481 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:481 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:36021 (36.0 KB) TX bytes:36021 (36.0 KB)
wlp13s0  Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 18:4f:32:2a:16:01
         UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
         RX packets:808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:558 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:932382 (932.3 KB)
         TX bytes:86607 (86.6 KB)

Now in order to get a wifi to work, what steps should I follow??

Comment: please format the shell output correctly

Comment: Is this okay? and please help me to get a my wifi connection..

Comment: May I ask you why you are shouting in the title?

Comment: I just tried to drive the point home buddy.My Wifi options were not visible and when I just disabled secure boot option, it came back but it's coming only if that secure boot option is disabled but then also I'm not able to access wifi.My laptop is getting connected to wifi just a couple of minutes an dthen again it's disconnected

Comment: So it isn't that the wifi isn't working; it is that it connects and then drops. Is that correct? If so, your question is a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/847392/wlan-rtl8723be-frequently-disconnects

Comment: If the secure boot option is disabled then only the wifi options are available.But then it connects for some time and then never shows the available wifi signals.It is like no wifi is available around me.When the secure boot option is enabled then the wifi option itself gets disappeared.

Comment: Is there a way to undo all the changes and I get the ubuntu as if I had freshly installed in PC