# HP Probook 450 G3 drivers

Tags: 14.04, hp

Hello I have 6th generation HP Probook 450 G3 and I installed **Ubuntu 14.04**, Unfortunately sound and WiFi don't work. Can someone refer me to the necessary driver links?

Thanks.

Comment: Try Ubuntu 16.04 it might work.

Comment: but ubuntu 14.04 is stable , is there any way to overcome with that

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/850046/edit) by adding the output of : `lspci -knn | grep net -A2` and `lspci | grep -i vga`

Answer (score 0):

As a comment above states try **Ubuntu 16.04**. Even then if Sound and WiFi don't work I found some links from other users with their problems and solutions.

When review the links below keep in mind some of them are a year old and might recommend something like "upgarde to Ubuntu 15.10" which you should not immediately try. Instead report back here with your status / problems and seek clarification.

#### No Sound

This link from HP website lists steps to get sound working under Ubuntu 15.10: ([hp.com - ProBook 450 G3 Ubuntu sound](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/ProBook-450-G3-Ubuntu-sound/td-p/5447804))

#### Broken WiFi

This link from Arch Linux ([Wireless driver for HP ProBook 450 G2](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=180957)) describes the Realtek RTL8723BE WiFi card problems. First ensure you have that card and then follow instructions ([How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-8723be-wireless-card-to-work)) in Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by upgrading my ubuntu 14.04 kernal 3.19 to 4.2

- sudo ap-get update
- sudo apt-get upgrade
- sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily