# Wi-Fi on ubuntu is too slow

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my HP 15-ay103nm and Wi-Fi network is too slow. It's supposed to be about 40Mb/s but it is about 7Mb/s. 
And Wi-Fi icon on top right is weird. Now it is full signal and for 30s will be half full.

Can someone help me how to fix this problem?

P. S. I have dual boot, legal Windows Home 10 and this Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
On Windows everything is excellent!

Comment: Not the good SE site. Go to ask ubuntu;  btw check your Wi-Fi card don't use a bugged driver

Comment: I've flagged it for a move to Ask-ubuntu, a moderator will probably do it soon ;)

Comment: "wierd"? Do you mean "weird" or "wired"?

Comment: @Alex I'm edited my question, WEIRD :)

Comment: Have you measured the actual speed by, say, downloading a large well seeded torrent or large iso from a popular website, on both windows and ubuntu?  That'll give you a more meaningful metric than looking at signal strength icons.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Run [this script](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) and [edit] your question with the output.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I solved my problem with this

http://askubuntu.com/a/635629/632598