# Cannot find wireless networks

Tags: networking, 16.04

Please note this question is not a duplicate of [How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work)

In that question, the user is able to get connections
to wireless networks and they get dropped intermittently. In my situation,
Ubuntu does not list any wireless networks to connect. Also, if you read the
comments section of this question, you will find that workaround mentioned
in the duplicate question has already been tried and that did not help.

Here is what was tried from answer in the duplicate question:
Downloaded rtlwifi and dkms pkg suggested by the duplicate question
and successfully ran 'sudo dpkg -i dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.10_all.deb'. Rebooted and find that the wireless device wlp2s0 no longer found when running 'ifconfig'. Also, wifi option in top right of the screen is no longer available. Since my situation got worse, removed the dkms package and
my wlp2s0 returned but still no wireless connection.

---

I have Ubuntu Xenial(16.04.2) installed and unable to find wireless networks
to connect to. Wireless switch is on and wireless networking is enabled and
the device is in a up state

```
wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:53:30:4d:84:27
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

More information on my setup:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:0383 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


 $ dmesg | grep -e wlan -e b43
[   15.006188] rtl8723be 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0

$ sudo modprobe b43
$
```

This is a dual boot system and when I boot with Windows 10, I am able to
find wireless networks and connect successfully with the same hardware.

Tried workaround mentioned in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work) but did not help.

Ubuntu is able to find wireless connection at home without any problem. When I go to a library, that's when Ubuntu fails to pick up any wireless network.

Rebooted Ubuntu and captured syslog messages when I was in a library. Here
are messages I see in the syslog that seemed relevant to me to debug the probem:

```
Feb 20 09:56:52 voyager kernel: [   14.026332] rtl8723be 0000:02:00.0:
enabling device (0000 -> 0003) Feb 20 09:56:52 voyager kernel: [  
14.051292] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi /rtl8723befw.bin Feb 20 09:56:52 voyager kernel: [   14.084384] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate
con trol algorithm 'rtl_rc' Feb 20 09:56:52 voyager kernel: [  
14.084789] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch  is on Feb 20 09:56:52 voyager kernel: [   14.086744] rtl8723be 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: re named
from wlan0 .... Feb 20 09:56:54 voyager NetworkManager[794]: <info> 
[1487602614.9362] NetworkMa nager (version 1.2.2) is starting... Feb
20 09:56:54 voyager NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1487602614.9365]
Read conf ig: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (etc:
default-wifi-powersave-on.conf ) Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager
thermald[820]: Unsupported cpu model, use thermal-conf.x ml file or
run with --ignore-cpuid-check Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager thermald[820]:
THD engine start failed Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager NetworkManager[794]:
<info>  [1487602615.1807] manager[0 x26811a0]: monitoring kernel
firmware directory '/lib/firmware'. Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager
NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1487602615.1808] monitorin g ifupdown
state file '/run/network/ifstate'. Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager
NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1487602615.3325] dns-mgr[0 x26930b0]:
set resolv-conf-mode: dnsmasq, plugin="dnsmasq" Feb 20 09:56:55
voyager NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1487602615.3326] dns-mgr[0
x26930b0]: using resolv.conf manager 'resolvconf' Feb 20 09:56:55
voyager NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1487602615.4015] rfkill1: found
WiFi radio killswitch (at
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.3/0000:02:00.
0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver rtl8723be) Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager
systemd[1]: Started Network Manager. Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager
systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Wait Online... Feb 20 09:56:55
voyager systemd[1]: Reached target Network. Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager
dbus[748]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name
='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.servic e' Feb 20 09:56:55
voyager systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher S
ervice... Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager ModemManager[795]: <info>  Couldn't
find support for dev ice at
'/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:01:00.0': not supported by
any  plugin Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager ModemManager[795]: <info> 
Couldn't find support for dev ice at
'/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.3/0000:02:00.0': not supported by
any  plugin ... Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager NetworkManager[794]: <info> 
[1487602615.8595] init! Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager NetworkManager[794]:
<info>  [1487602615.8600] managemen t mode: unmanaged Feb 20 09:56:55
voyager NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1487602615.8608] devices a dded
(path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0,
iface:  enp1s0) Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager NetworkManager[794]: <info> 
[1487602615.8608] device ad ded (path:
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0, iface:
enp1s0): no ifupdown configuration found. Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager
NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1487602615.8609] devices a dded (path:
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.3/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0, iface: 
wlp2s0) Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager NetworkManager[794]: <info> 
[1487602615.8609] device ad ded (path:
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.3/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0, iface:
wlp2s0): no ifupdown configuration found. Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager
NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1487602615.8609] devices a dded (path:
/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo) Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager
NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1487602615.8609] device ad ded (path:
/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration fo
und. Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager NetworkManager[794]: <info> 
[1487602615.8609] end _init . Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager
NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1487602615.8610] settings:  loaded
plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use
the NetworkManager mailing list.
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-set
tings-plugin-ifupdown.so) Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager NetworkManager[794]:
<info>  [1487602615.8615] SettingsP lugin-Ofono: init! Feb 20 09:56:55
voyager NetworkManager[794]: <warn>  [1487602615.8616] SettingsP
lugin-Ofono: file doesn't exist: /var/lib/ofono Feb 20 09:56:55
voyager NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1487602615.8616] SettingsP
lugin-Ofono: end _init. Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager NetworkManager[794]:
<info>  [1487602615.8616] settings:  loaded plugin ofono: (C)
2013-2016 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use th e
NetworkManager mailing list.
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-s
ettings-plugin-ofono.so) Feb 20 09:56:55 voyager NetworkManager[794]:
<info>  [1487602615.8616] (40512336 ) ... get_connections. Feb 20
09:56:55 voyager NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1487602615.8617]
(40512336 ) ... get_connections (managed=false): return empty list.
```

Full part of syslog messages is available [here](http://pastebin.com/W4BuC74W)

Comment: Symptoms described in above link is random disconnects. In my case, I am not even able to connect once. Solution mentioned in the link is to install the package 'rtlwifi-new-dkms' using apt-get. I am offline in Ubuntu currently and cannot do a straight update. Could do the offline approach suggested in the same link, which is to download rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.10_all.deb and dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb packages built for Ubuntu 15.10 and install it on my 16.04 system. Is that worth trying or would that cause more problems because of difference in versions of Ubuntu? Thanks

Comment: Symptoms may vary. You can download https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.10_all.deb

Comment: Saved the above rtlwifi package and got dkms pkg from the other link and successfully ran 'sudo dpkg -i dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.10_all.deb'.  Rebooted and find that the wireless device wlp2s0 no longer found when running 'ifconfig'. Also, wifi option in top right of the screen is no longer available. Not sure what to do now.

Comment: You can always revert it by `sudo apt purge rtlwifi-new-dkms`.

Comment: Did 'sudo apt purge rtlwifi-new-dkms' and rebooted. Back to original shape. Now got back the wireless device but no connections.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: I ran 'wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info'. No output file got created, but instead I got this error: 'Resolving github.com (github.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘github.com’'. Possibly because I am not online in Ubuntu.

Comment: I am not sure why this question is marked as a duplicate. Please see above comments, I already tried the solution mentioned in http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work and it did not help.

Comment: For the wireless diagnostic script you need to refer to the section that starts with “If you cannot connect to the internet” (the 4th paragraph).

Comment: The linked question has an accepted answer that is confirmed to work by the author of the question. It may also work for similar problems and is worth a try considering how easy it is to implement. Could you please [edit] your question to describe what you tried and what happened? Thanks.

Comment: The 4th paragraph suggests that I would have to move files to a platform which is network enabled to post the output generated. It does not give any alternate command to run in case one is offline. The command which starts with 'wget ...' does not generate any output for me and fails with 'wget: unable to resolve host address github.com'. Please note that I am totally offline in Ubuntu when it does not work. I could however post the same output when I go home, when Ubuntu wireless connection always works. Not sure if such output would be useful since it is captured when things are working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem resolved after running this step

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

followed by a reboot as mentioned here

[How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work)

Comment: Very considerate of you to come back and answer almost 1 year later. +1