# WiFi issues with RTL8723BE on 14.04

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

WiFi won't connect even after plenty of troubleshooting.

1. WiFi takes a long time to connect.
2. Even after successful connection (which is rare), the internet connectivity works for a maximum of 10 minutes after which it stops sending and receiving data.

Output to `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:81c1]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

[Wireless info script result](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25355002/)

Followed the steps in the link [RealTek](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work) to the dot.  This is what happened:

**Input**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

After this, there is no option of a wireless connection whatsoever.

[No wireless option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtrZb.png)

**Output** for `dkms status`

```
bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 4.4.0-92-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.10~trusty, 4.4.0-92-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**Output** for `lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   20480  2 
rfcomm                 69632  8 
binfmt_misc            20480  1 
mac80211              733184  0 
amdkfd                131072  1 
uvcvideo               90112  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
radeon               1503232  1 
videodev              180224  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
intel_rapl             20480  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0 
intel_powerclamp       16384  0 
coretemp               16384  0 
kvm                   536576  0 
snd_soc_skl            49152  0 
snd_soc_skl_ipc        32768  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       28672  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc        16384  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_dsp        53248  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1 
snd_soc_core          212992  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 snd_soc_sst_dsp
snd_hda_intel          40960  3 
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
ttm                    94208  1 radeon
cfg80211              561152  1 mac80211
snd_hda_core           73728  7 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_skl
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  8 snd_hda_ext_core,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_skl,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
i915_bpo             1306624  4 
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
hci_uart               77824  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0 
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
hp_wmi                 16384  0 
snd                    81920  19 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
aesni_intel           167936  0 
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
intel_ips              20480  1 i915_bpo
drm_kms_helper        151552  2 i915_bpo,radeon
btusb                  45056  0 
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  2 btusb,hci_uart
btintel                16384  2 btusb,hci_uart
bluetooth             516096  27 bnep,btbcm,btqca,btrtl,btusb,hci_uart,rfcomm,btintel
soundcore              16384  1 snd
joydev                 20480  0 
shpchp                 36864  0 
input_leds             16384  0 
serio_raw              16384  0 
tpm_crb                16384  0 
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
drm                   360448  8 ttm,i915_bpo,drm_kms_helper,radeon
i2c_hid                20480  0 
hid                   118784  1 i2c_hid
mei_me                 36864  0 
video                  40960  1 i915_bpo
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    28672  0 
pinctrl_intel          20480  1 pinctrl_sunrisepoint
intel_lpss_acpi        16384  0 
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_acpi
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915_bpo,radeon
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
parport_pc             36864  0 
processor_thermal_device    16384  0 
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
ppdev                  20480  0 
mac_hid                16384  0 
int3400_thermal        16384  0 
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
hp_wireless            16384  0 
acpi_pad               24576  0 
lp                     20480  0 
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
psmouse               131072  0 
r8169                  81920  0 
ahci                   36864  3 
mii                    16384  1 r8169
libahci                32768  1 ahci
fjes                   28672  0
```

Update:

`wl` removed.

`rfkill` list output:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have added the output.  And also the wireless info script result.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work)

Comment: No such file exists.

Comment: Problem update:  The system is no longer detecting WiFi.  (Error: device not ready)

Comment: @Pilot6 I've edited the query.  I would appreciate it if someone could figure anything out.  In a real fix here.

Comment: It is not `lpsci`, but `lspci`. The problem is probably with the kernel version. A real fix is to remove the package from my PPA because it does't build for the 4.4 kernel that you probably have. We are guessing here. You gave no information. You can install a driver from git.

Comment: What's the output of `dkms status` and `lsmod`?

Comment: Sorry for the lpsci fiasco.  I was sleep deprived and quite frustrated.  The problem, anyway, persists.  Added dkms status and lsmod.

Comment: Please also add output of `rfkill list`. And also remove `wl` by `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Comment: But a guaranteed solution will be to install 16.04.

Comment: Even I want to just upgrade to 16.04.  I don't think anything short of a competent ubuntu user's physical access to my system is gonna solve this problem in 14.04.
But 14.04 is supposedly better than 16.04 for machine learning.  And that's my sole purpose of using Ubuntu.
So I am in a real fix here.

Comment: Why 14.04 may be better in learning? On 16.04 your wireless device is supported out of the box.