# LAN connection and Wifi

Tags: wireless, lan

Some particular WIFI and LAN cable (D Link) internet is not connecting in ubuntu 17:10.  And same connection working fine in windows.

Wifi is not even detecting. LAN is showing but no internet connectivity.

Please help

riaz@Kaguya:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for riaz: 
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: 18:60:24:4b:43:3f
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.181 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:124 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1200000-b1200fff memory:b1000000-b1003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: f8:28:19:75:9a:c3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.13.0-16-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1100000-b1103fff
riaz@Kaguya:~$

@EODCraftStaff

Comment: Please add the output of sudo lshw -C network to your question. There is not enough info for anyone to help.

Comment: Edited Post with output of  sudo lshw -C  @EODCraftStaff

Comment: He did not ask for sudo lshw -C; he asked for sudo lshw -C network. Please try again.

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work You probably only need the `ant_sel` step.

Comment: WIFI is still unable to connect , pls help