# Unable to connect certain Wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, hp

[image]I am Unable to connect to Broadband Wifi in Ubuntu 16.04 in HP Notebook 15
while I am able to connect it with Window and Android mobile.

Below is info about my Wifi Driver and Hardware.

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI 
Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
0d:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe 
Wireless Network Adapter
```

rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

uname -r

```
4.13.0-37-generic
```

nmcli dev wifi list

```
 SSID     MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
 vivek_m  Infra  1     54 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
```

and sometime

nmcli dev wifi list

```
 SSID     MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
 vivek_m  Infra  1     54 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA2     
 pg 1     Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  WPA2
```

Currently I am unable to connect with pg1 and other pg2 is not showing in list while I am connected with android with pg2 at same time,

Sometime the pg2 connection is available in wifi list but not in command list,
Please check screenshot, it is listed in wifi list in light shed and when I click on this It gave me an error:

```
(7) The access point /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/109 was
not in the scan list.
```

sudo lshw -c network

```
 network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: enp7s0
   version: 07
   serial: 70:5a:0f:97:e8:cc
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet         physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169    driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12     latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c5000000-c5000fff    memory:c5100000-c5103fff
  -network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
   logical name: wlp13s0
   version: 00
   serial: 44:1c:a8:73:7d:25
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.13.0-37-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.204 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3000000-c3003fff
```

iwconfig

```
enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp13s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"vivek_m"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: CC:61:E5:42:7B:63   
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1701   Missed beacon:0
```

Please let me know if something else needs here to answer and help me to connect to connect this Wifi.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `uname -r`

Comment: Also add: `nmcli dev wifi list`

Comment: @chili555 Hi there! Sorry I was not available for few days for editing.

Comment: I suspect that you need the ant_sel step here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work/635629#635629

Comment: I did it but didn't work, tried

Comment: Did you try both `ant_sel=1` and then `ant_sel=2`? Did neither give better signal strength?

Comment: @chili55 Hi there 'ant_sel=1' it worked, I appreciate this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove the settings you made.

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

If you do not have this file, nothing is wrong.

Then install a good driver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

Reboot and enjoy

If you still have problems (low signal), you may need to add an option:

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

or

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"  | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```