# Realtek rtl8723be giving very low signal in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, wireless, 18.04, ppa, rtl8723be

I am using HP 15-ac173TU with a wireless chipcard from Realtek, rtl8723be. I was using Ubuntu 16.04 before and also encountered this problem and solved it using this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/635629/792541).

Now when I have cleaned installed 18.04(due to some problems, I couldn't update from 16.04), it is blocking me when I try to run this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
```

which gives me the output as:

```
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic Release     
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I am guessing that [Pilot6](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi) hasn't issued any release for bionic of this driver, and so I am getting this 404 error. 
I have also tried using this command:

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

and making a .conf file in the directory but still, it isn't helping me as the signal is very low.

I have installed Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows, although, when I am using Windows there isn't any problem as in Windows it chooses the antenna by itself.

I just want to know that is there any other way that I can rectify this problem and use my wireless without doing this. 
I have also seen this GitHub [repository](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new), but he clearly states that as I am using Ubuntu my APIs are modified. Hence, I couldn't use it.

I have researched and got this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032114/792541) also, but it didn't make any sense doing it as I don't have any driver as mentioned in the answer.

I have done practically everything but still am getting this problem. Hope anyone in the community is kind to help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: To continue using the system consider removing [obsolete PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi) with `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi`.

Comment: @pomsky After I tried `ant_sel=1` instead of `ant_sel=2`, the `iwconfig` command gives the `Bit rate = 7.2 mb/s` which in contrast with the later gives `72.2 mb/s`

Comment: @N0rbert I have already done that and tried to add the PPA again but it showed the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi networks not found ubuntu 18.04 with rtl8723be.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069153/wifi-networks-not-found-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be) It seems kernel v4.15.0-33 has a bug. Alternatively, try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068826/wifi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts