# Wifi networks not found ubuntu 18.04 with rtl8723be

Tags: wireless, realtek, realtek-wireless, rtl8723be

I had recently updated to Ubuntu 18.04. All was working fine until today morning when I was not able to connect to the wifi. When I try to scan for networks it shows no networks found. When I run `iwlist wlo1 scan` I get the following results:

`wlo1      No scan results`

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 but managed to fix by changing the `antenna_sel` parameter as per [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2343357) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04) by using:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl7823be 
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=x
```

The value of `x` being either 1 or 2, whichever gives better results for wifi signals. However, when I try the same solution for 18.04 it doesn't seem to work. I have looked for solutions for 18.04 and found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032099/how-do-i-get-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work-on-18-04) [this answer](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/363). There deosn't seem to be any conclusive answer on how to fix the problem. I decided to uninstall rtl8723be drivers using `sudo apt purge rtl8723be` and reinstall using [this](https://akshaycv006.wordpress.com/2017/01/12/installing-realtek-rtl8723be-driver-for-ubuntu-debian-or-fedora/) however when I try to do that I get errors (when I run this command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi`) such as:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I then installed the rtl8723be driver using instructions as per the github page for rtlwifi_new in [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new). The installation was sucessful however I was back to square one, no wifi networks found. Does anyone know how to get the wireless to working? I'll post the output of `lshw -class network` below:

```
  *-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 00
   serial: 70:77:81:12:fc:2d
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.15.0-33-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:18 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:c6100000-c6103fff


*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 0a
   serial: 3c:a8:2a:ae:31:82
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=145.94.38.86 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:19 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c6004000-c6004fff memory:c6000000-c6003fff
```

PS: The LAN works just fine, the problem is just with the wireless interface.

EDIT: The problem is solved with an update to 18.10 as it uses kernel 17.0.

Comment: See this for a different solution: [Wifi doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068826/wifi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts)

Comment: Here's another workaround: https://askubuntu.com/a/1085273/480481

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid I don't have an exact answer to your question, but I am having the **exact** same problem and found a workaround to get my wifi running on my laptop again.

Run in terminal: `uname -r`
Does it say `4.15.0-33-generic`?

**My solution:**
When booting the laptop, select *advanced startup options* (as if you were trying to select *recovery mode*) and select *kernel 4.15.0-32-generic*.
(When entering this menu, I had multiple options/kernels to choose from - some were listed as (recovery mode) and others were normal - I chose the non-recovery entry.)  I will try to google my way to a better fix and post back if I find it.

Comment: Wow! That worked, wifi is working again! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try some basic:
Plug wifi dongle in a different usb port.
make sure you have the latest version of the following installed: linux-headers-generic build-essential git.
Try putting your module in etc/modules to load at boot.
Verify module is not in the blacklist file.
Make sure your on the latest release of 18.4 Apt-get update & upgrade.
Bring down your network manager then restart it.

TC.

Comment: Tried all of it, unfortunately, nothing worked! However, the solution by @Evros of changing the kernel from 4.15.0-33-generic to 4.15.0-32-generic in the advance options worked!

Answer (score 0):

The bug is fixed with this kernel: [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~jsalisbury/lp1788997](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ejsalisbury/lp1788997)

as long as you select antenna 1:

```
modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

Make sure you have that in config too:

```
sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf'
```