# Xubuntu 16.04 wireless not working anymore on ms-1688

Tags: networking, drivers, xubuntu

**Problem**: Xubuntu 16.04 wireless is not working.

First my system, from `uname -a`

```
Linux clessidra 4.13.0-43-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 17 13:00:11 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

result of `rfkill list` is nothing

Result of `ifconfig -a`

```
enp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW 6c:62:6d:28:80:9f  
          indirizzo inet:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
          indirizzo inet6: fe80::e5f8:c6ed:5acb:b738/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5722 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:6120180 (6.1 MB)  Byte TX:555816 (555.8 KB)
          Interrupt:24 Indirizzo base:0x7000 

lo        Link encap:Loopback locale  
          indirizzo inet:127.0.0.1  Maschera:255.0.0.0
          indirizzo inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:556 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:556 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:49950 (49.9 KB)  Byte TX:49950 (49.9 KB)
```

Output for `lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 03
       serial: 6c:62:6d:28:80:9f
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.045.08-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:24 ioport:a000(size=256) memory:f2a04000-f2a04fff memory:f2a00000-f2a03fff
```

And then `iwconfig`:

```
enp6s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I've tried to [install realteck drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work) but no luck here, during install command result:

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.13.0-43-generic (i686)
```

I've tried also to get networking service status, using: sudo service networking status and receive:

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: active (exited) since dom 2018-05-27 16:03:03 CEST; 20min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 495 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 492 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 495 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/networking.service

mag 27 16:03:03 clessidra systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
mag 27 16:03:03 clessidra systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
```

So my question is:

1. why wifi interface is no more available?
2. why I'm able to connect using ethernet, but not wifi ? From my perspective, seems to be because no interface has wifi support, right ?
3. how to install a working driver and have wifi support back ?

Note:

1. this laptop is old, is a cx620 with model name ms-1688
2. I don't want to upgrade ubuntu version and stay on xubuntu (that works perfectly in my case until yesterday)
3. I've also already tried to disabled uefi boot stuff, but there is no option on bios

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `sudo lshw -C network` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I've provided requested information, thanks to you!

Comment: VTR as there is now enough information to answer this question.

Comment: I see no wireless network adapter listed with which a hypothetical device driver could interface. Are you sure it's enabled (for internal devices) or connected (for external add-on devices)? In the case of an external network adapter, how is it connected to the machine in question?

Comment: it's an internal device. I wonder if there is a way to check if "hardware button" is stuck or not, because seems not working anymore?

Comment: What's the output to `rfkill list`?  Ping me @fabby after you've [edit]ed your question qnd provided the output.

Comment: @Fabby I've tried to run rfkill list and output is nothing

Comment: I've tried also to update kernet and after many problems, go back to 4.4.0-128 with xubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, but problem is still here..

Comment: It is a hardware issue.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your output the reason wireless doesn't work is that your particular laptop doesn't have the optional wifi **or if it does, the card is faulty**.

The specs are as follows:

```
• Intel® Core™ i3 Processor  
• Genuine Windows® 7 Home Premium
(MSI recommends upgrade to Genuine Windows® 7 Professional)
• 15.6” 16:9 wide screen display
• Easy-to-carry lightweight design
• ATi HD545V with DDR3 512MB VRAM graphics card
• 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN with Bluetooth (optional)
• HDMI (High-Definition Multimedia Interface) Output
• Exclusive GPU Boost Technology
• msi Exclusive ECO Engine Power Management System
```

The fact that it doesn't show up in the lshw command indicates that it isn't there (or isn't connected). If your certain that you have one, **visually verify that it exists and insure that it's properly connected.**

[Source](https://de.msi.com/Laptop/CX620MX.html)

Comment: my laptop does have wifi card, at least last week was working. I wonder if it is possible that I have a problem on "activate wifi" button, there is a way from software to test it ?

Comment: @vokail if that were the case it would show up with the `rfkill list` command. The fact that it doesn't show up in the `lshw` command indicates that it isn't there (or isn't connected). If your certain that you have one, visually verify that it exists and insure that it's properly connected.

Comment: I can confirm it

Comment: **Elder Geek:** Your hunch was correct before I asked about `rfkill list`! **@Vokail** Don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: Well I'm not sure to understand, my laptop does have wifi-card and is not working, so why accept the answer ?

Comment: @Vokail I'm not sure I understand either, it looks to me like my answer is correct. According to your question "result of rfkill list is nothing" I added the content of [my comment](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek) which it appears that you might not have seen to the answer.

Comment: I have solved buying a wifi usb adapter, my wifi card seems not working anymore (even if propertly connected).

Comment: @Vokail Thats not too surprising, as I indicated in my answer that your card was either missing or broken (faulty). I'm glad you got the problem resolved. Cheers!