# No WiFi networks are detected

Tags: networking, wireless

**OS:** Budgie Ubuntu 16.04

**Adapter**: RTL8723BE Realtek Wireless Network Adapter

I also have Windows on dual-boot, and the wifi works on Windows so this is not a hardware problem. I have Tried reinstalling the `bcmwl-kernel-source`, tried restarting the `network-manager`, but nothing has worked.

Sometimes, it detects my own WiFi and connects to it but there is no internet access. (It doesn't detect the other wifi networks, even then.)

Comment: I had similar issues with wifi on Ubuntu 16.04.
They disappeared after ugrading Ubuntu to 18.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work)

Comment: Broadcom is not related at all.

Answer (score 0):

Quite often, the weak signal is a symptom of the antenna wire being connected to connection #1 on the card when the default driver is expecting to see the signal at connection #2. Of course, you could open the laptop and switch the wire or you could implement antenna selection at the driver level.

From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
exit
```

Reboot. Is there any improvement? If not, run the sequence again with ant_sel=1 and reboot again.