# Wifi not working on Ubuntu 16.04 after just being installed alongside Windows 10

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, realtek-wireless, rtl8723be

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the installation went smoothly but I can't seem to connect to WiFi, the button to select networks is greyed and it shows WiFi Network disconnected. I have looked through the other threads and none seem to be working...

My laptop uses Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11 bgn Wi-Fi Adapter

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of missing drivers, if you have a LAN cable:

- connect your device to the internet
- open **Software & Updates**
- go to the 5th Tab named Additional Drivers and wait until you see the right driver for your device

  - apply the changes

[Edit]

It seems to be the same problem, download the driver on this way.

[How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

Reboot your device

I hope it could solve your problem. Let me know if it was helpful.

David

Comment: Nothing is showing in additional drivers, it displays No additonal drivers available

Comment: So you were able to establish a wired connection before you have tried that?